# Extending functionality in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does prototype extend on typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766117/how-does-prototype-extend-on-typescript)

I am currently learning TypeScript, and would like to know how it is possible to add functionality to existing objects. Say I want to add an implementation for Foo to the String object. In JavaScript I would do this:

```
String.prototype.Foo = function() {
    // DO THIS...
}
```

Understanding that TypeScript classes, interfaces and modules are open ended led me to try the following, without success

*1. Reference the JavaScript implementation from TypeScript*

```
    JavaScript:

    String.prototype.Foo = function() {
        // DO THIS...
    }

    TypeScript:

    var x = "Hello World";
    x.Foo(); //ERROR, Method does not exist
```

*2. Extend the interface*

```
interface String {
    Foo(): number;
}

var x = "Hello World";
x.Foo(); //Exists but no implementation.
```

*3. Extend the class*

```
class String {
    Foo(): number {
        return 0;
    }
}

// ERROR: Duplicate identifier 'String'
```

As you can see from these results, so far I have been able to add the method via an interface contract, but no implementation, so, how do I go about defining AND implementing my Foo method as part of the pre-existing String class?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I have found the solution. It takes a combination of the interface and the JavaScript implementation. The interface provides the contract for TypeScript, allowing visibility of the new method. The JavaScript implementation provides the code that will be executed when the method is called.

**Example:**

```
interface String {
    foo(): number;
}

String.prototype.foo= function() {
    return 0;
}
```

**As of TypeScript 1.4 you can now also extend static members:**

```
interface StringConstructor {
    bar(msg: string): void;
}

String.bar = function(msg: string) {
    console.log("Example of static extension: " + msg);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, that's how it is meant to be. Remember, TypeScript is not a language in itself, it is just a syntactic sugar. So writing something in 'JavaScript style' is a good practice that has no drawbacks whatsoever.

Comment: Does this solution really work with **String**? Because I'm doing the _exact_ same thing and get compile errors that the property doesn't exist on the String type. What am I missing? (using tsc 1.4.1)

Comment: @sebas2day yes it works - http://tinyurl.com/ouwh3ln

Comment: @series0ne that's interesting. It does compile indeed, but it gives me an error anyway. Very strange...

Comment: @sebas2day are you targetting an older version of the compiler (i.e. pre 1.4), this has caused me problems in the past.

Comment: @series0ne yes you were right, it was using the TSC compiler of "Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript". Solved it now. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work for me in 1.8 with custom types. TS claims that the prototype doesn't have the added method in the interface (e.g. `foo`), even though the class implements the interface (though it doesn't implement the function in the interface), so I can't implement it (e.g. `prototype.foo = ...`) in the separate file.

Comment: @Josh, what do you mean by custom types? i.e. a TypeScript class or a JavaScript object for which you have created an ambient declaration?

Comment: I mean a TypeScript class that I created that implements the interface, not String, as in the answer, which seems to somehow be both an interface and class at the same time (interfaces don't have prototypes AFAICT). You can "implement" the added function via indexing the class, like `Foo['bar'] = ...`, but that doesn't indicate to TypeScript that the class implements the interface's function so it still throws a compiler error for the class incorrectly implementing the interface.

Comment: @Josh could you possibly post your code into the TypeScript playground and share so I can see what the error is?

Comment: Sure: http://tinyurl.com/gtqwsfr

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not saying that your question or answer is invalid. I'm just pointing out that I think it may only work in specific cases (built-in types maybe) and not as a general solution in case others happen upon this as I did and expect it to work.

Comment: @Josh yes this is for built in types - this sort of thing WILL work for custom types that are implemented in JAVASCRIPT but WILL NOT work for custom types that are built in TYPESCRIPT

Comment: @Josh see here... http://tinyurl.com/gsag7gg

Comment: @OlegMihailik Aren't **all** langues just syntactic sugar?

Comment: Use `Object.defineProperty` instead of adding prototype directly like that

Comment: @Arijoon why? Okay I know why but the TypeScript compiler doesn't output things like that, and what happens if you're targeting ES3?

Comment: the question now is, how wrap that in a module and import it in other modules ?????

Comment: code above doesnt work(

Comment: @RamzanChasygov which version of TypeScript are you targeting?

Comment: @series0ne, "2.5.2"

Comment: @RamzanChasygov that’s unusual. That should definitely work. What errors are you getting?

Comment: @series0ne, if copypast code above, `[ts] Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'String'.`

Comment: Are you using foo as a static or instance property?

Comment: @series0ne, instance, also throws warning `[ts] 'String' is declared but its value is never read.`

Comment: It sounds like the default lib.d.ts isn’t being imported properly. There is also an issue with TS 2.5 where lib.d.ts isn’t imported properly for certain targets. I would consider updating to the latest version of TypeScript (2.9 now I think)

Comment: @series0ne, updated ts, updated `tsconfig.json` from [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), doesnt help(

Comment: @series0ne, in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) everything works, maybe some kinda error for my os(Ubuntu 17)

Comment: In case anyone else has the same problem I did:
I used the code here, and found it worked. BUT, if I use it in a module (i.e. with an `export` statement) then I get the error `[ts] Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'String'.` (in both VS Code and the playground) . The fix is to make the interface global:
`declare global { interface String { foo(): number; } }`.

Comment: @ZSmith It works. Is this a safe way to extend it?

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim I think so. It's given as an example at the very bottom of this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim "Is this a safe way to extend it?" - In general it's considered bad practice to extend existing JavaScript objects in this way, and with good reason. There's a lot of literature worth reading on this topic, starting here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: @series0ne Thanks a lot :) It was very helpful indeed!