# Typescript - Adding a function to a defined type

Tags: typescript

I am in the process of translating some of my code over, and I have noticed a peculiar behavior with the typing enforcement. I am not sure it is 'peculiar', it may very well be expected, but I am curious as to how to get around it.

For this example, I am using `Kendo UI`'s `kendoWindow` widget, but almost any 'type' from any kind of library is sufficient to demonstrate it.

```
export function UserWindow(options) {
   var settings = $.extend({
     // default settings
   }, options);

   var $WINDOW = <kendo.ui.Window> {};

   $WINDOW = $("<div id='kendo-editor-window' />")
       .kendoWindow(settings) // this is where we have now declared the type, basically
       .data("kendoWindow");

   // here, I want to add my own little method to kendoWindow for the purpose of how
   // I intend to use it!
   $WINDOW.databind = function(e) {  // this is where we run into trouble!
       // some code goes here
   }

   return $WINDOW;
}
```

Now under normal Javascript, this does not give me any trouble. But `.databind(e)` is not a defined function of `kendoWindow`, and therefore it is actually balking at me adding it like this.

I have been able to get around it by not declaring the variable as a type of `kendo.ui.Window`, but I would like to discover how to APPROPRIATELY handle this situation, in other words, extend the type properly so that I get intellisense and the whole type safety thing if it is at all possible.

Comment: The same applies in your case as with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897659/extending-functionality-in-typescript You will need to find out what interface you need to add your `databind` function to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic type checking should (and will) prevent you from assigning to a non existent variable (`databind` in your case). So you need to tell typescript that such a function exists before you can assign it. Its easily done since interfaces are open ended in TypeScript, so add the following code :

```
module kendo.ui{
    export interface Window{
        databind: Function;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws a 'duplicate identifier' exception. I'm not entirely certain why. `Window` is declared as a class, not an interface.