# ionic2 typescript compilation error for adding a method to String or Number

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, ionic2

In my Ionic2 project, I am trying to add a new method to Number as in the following code.

```
interface StringConstructor {
  bar(msg: string): void;
}

String.bar = function(msg: string) {
  alert("Example of static extension: " + msg);
}

String.bar("Hello World");


interface NumberConstructor {
  toRad(): number;
}

Number.toRad = function() { return this * (Math.PI / 180); }; 

export function gpsDist() {
  
}
```

When I do ionic build, it gives me the following errors:

> TypeScript error:
> /Users/cju/Projects/Bus2-App/app/util/mathUtil.ts(7,8): Error TS2339:
> Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'StringConstructor'.
>
> TypeScript error: /Users/cju/Projects/Bus2-App/app/util/mathUtil.ts(11,8): Error
> TS2339: Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'StringConstructor'.
>
> TypeScript error:
> /Users/cju/Projects/Bus2-App/app/util/mathUtil.ts(18,8): Error TS2339:
> Property 'toRad' does not exist on type 'NumberConstructor'.

However the same file compiles ok outside ionic. If I compile it with tsc, I get no errors. All the code are in one file.

Comment: I tried to compile the file outside "ionic build" command by doing "node tsc.js myfile.ts" and "node typescript.js myfile.ts", both compile without error. The tsc.js and typescript.js come from ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript/node_modules/tsify/node_modules/typescript/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Angular takes care of ts compilation, you can edit the typescript compiler options in the file `tsconfig.json` which is in the root of your app. But I don't think you want to mess with that.

Try the non-static way to extend functionality that you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897813/1016128

Comment: I did this. 


    interface Number { toRad(): number; } Number.prototype.toRad = function() { return this * 2; };  


It still gives me the error "Error TS2339: Property 'toRad' does not exist on type 'Number'." But it still runs and gives me the correct result.