# Extending class with no copying constructor (with private param)

Tags: angularjs, typescript

During trying to enhance Angular's ComponetFixture I noticed that this can not be done because of no copying constructor for this class. (Or am I wrong?)

Let's suppose we have a class:

```
class A
{
  constructor(public pub, private priv) { }
}
```

And I want to create class BetterA based on class A, so:

```
class BetterA extends A
{
  constructor(a: A)
  {
    // super(a);    <----- this can not be done, so maybe...

    // super(a.pub, a.priv)  // ...this could be better option, but...
  }

  myFunction(a: string) { return a; }
}
```

...second parameter is PRIVATE. I can not access it ;/

What can I do in that case?

I know that one of solutions is to use prototype like this:

```
A.prototype['myFunction'] = function(a: string) { return a; } // this must be done with function keyword, it's not working with ()=>{} !!! /there are problem with this pointer/
```

But then I have to write something weird like this:

```
console.log(  classAobject['myFunction']("abc")  );
```

Instead of

```
console.log(  classAobject.myFunction("abc")  );
```

*or*

I can do it by composition:

```
class B
{
  public a: A; // or constructor(public a: A)
  myFunction(a) { return a; }
}
```

But is seems not too elegant.

Is there any better solution?

**Edit #1**

I've just discovered that this syntax:

```
Class.prototype.NewFunction = function() { this.x.y.z = 123 }
```

is valid but it produces compiler errors, **code works** but we get:

> 'Property 'TextOf' does not exist on type 'Class'

and when you try to call it like this:

```
objectOfClass.NewFunction()
```

makes:

> 'Property 'NewFunction' does not exist on type 'Class'

BUT

It's gonna working only when we use **function** keyword. When we use lambda expression there will be same strange invisible problems with some functions.

Comment: Does your last example with composition solve your functional need? If so I see no problem with that.

Comment: This could solve my problem but now I need to change my code in many places instead of change the class declaration. I tried to use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13897813/4584448 solution similar to the first one but without indexer notatnion ['myFunction'] but it's not working ;/

Comment: I think many us us aren't familiar with how you need to use this. It would be awesome if you could provide sample code for the usage of `BetterA`.

Answer (score 0):

I think composition is the way to go here. please remember that you are building a class and not a method which requires the new operator in order to instantiate your object. this may be what your looking for

```
class A{
  tPub;
  constructor(public pub, private priv) {
   this.tPub=pub
  }
}
class B extends A{
 constructor(pub){
  super(pub)
 }
 myFunc(){} //equiv to B.prototype.myFunc
}

export const myClass=new B();


//another file
import {myClass} from './file'
let m=myClass.myFunc();
```

unfortunately, by setting priv to private it will do exactly what it is told and make it a private object. you also could do without the constructor depending on what you would like to do with your class.