# Angular2 & Typescript: How to add string extension method/prototype

Tags: angular, typescript, extension-methods

I want to add extension method `format()` to `String`. So my expectation is that I can use `String.format` wherever in my project.
I had followed the guideline of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897659/extending-functionality-in-typescript) but this not help. I got this error:
[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

p.s: I want to add the extension method like I did in angular 1.xx

[image]

---

**Edit**

use `declare global` won't get error.

```
declare global {
interface String {
    format(): string;
}}

String.prototype.format = function () :string {
var result = arguments[0];
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
    var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
    result = result.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
}
return result;}
```

How we use `String.format('<img alt="{0}" title="{0}" src="{1}" />', name, id);`
Since `format` does not require parameters

Comment: Whatever you have should work. [Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20String%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo()%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AString.prototype.foo%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: It should be mentioned that is is a terrible practice. Extendng prototypes isn't a good practice either, but String.format is not even a prototype method - the latter would have a benefit of using it like '...'.format() at least. Using globals as namespaces in TypeScript makes no sense. Use modules. If you did this in A1 and switched to A2 and TS, it looks like there's a good chance to stop doing that at last.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20String%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo()%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AString.prototype.foo%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%203%3B%0D%0A%7D) it works just fine.

It probably doesn't work for you because you're probably using modules (import/export), in that case you need to do that in the [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation):

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        foo(): number;
    }
}
```

Then you won't get an error when adding `foo` to the prototype.

---

#### Edit

Seems like you want a static function on `String`, so you need to do this:

```
declare global {
    interface StringConstructor {
        format(): string;
    }
}

String.format = function (...args: string[]) {
    ...
}
```

I also added the `...args: string[]` to the signature which tells the compiler that the function expects any number of strings as arguments.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Use `declare global` won't get error. But how can I declare a method in typescript that I can pass any multiple parameters?
`declare global {
    interface String {
        format(): string;
    }
}

String.prototype.format = function() {
    var result = arguments[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
        var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
        result = result.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
    }
    return result;
}`

I could not use:
`String.prototype.format('<img alt="{0}" title="{0}" src="{1}" />',name, id);`

Comment: 1. Don't put code in comments, instead edit your question and put the code there, then simply comment on an answer and write that the question was updated, 2. Check my revised answer

Comment: As I wrote in my updated answer, you need to add the `format` function to the `String` class (`StringConstructor`) as static method, and not to the prototype...

Comment: Your solution is my expectation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10):

For me the following worked in an Angular 6 project using TypeScript 2.8.4.

In the typings.d.ts file add:

```
interface String {
  format(...args: string[]): string;
}
```

Note: No need to 'declare global'.

In a new file called string.extensions.ts add the following:

```
interface String {
  format(...args: string[]): string;
}

String.prototype.format = function (...args: string[]): string {
  var s = this;
  return s.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
    return (typeof args[number] != 'undefined') ? args[number] : match;
  });
};
```

To use it, first import it:

```
import '../../string.extensions';
```

Obviously your import statement should point to the correct path.
Inside your class's constructor or any method:

```
console.log("Hello {0}".format("world"));
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me a lot. In case someone needs it, you can add a shortcut in the tsconfig.json: `"paths": {
  "@extensions/*": [
    "./*.extensions.ts"
  ]
}` and use it like this: `import '@extensions/string';`

Comment: nice tip on the paths @Gus

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This works with Angular 6 and `declare global` isn't the best way to go about things and `import` is provdided specfically to avoid that.

Comment: I don't see a `typings.d.ts`, should I create it ? Where ? And how do I include it in the solution ?

Comment: @Robouste you can create it in the src folder. See my post on using it, i.e. "To use it, first import it"...

Comment: @Gus's suggestion is great. Just make sure to add `paths` under field `compilerOptions`