# String prototype works in browser but not in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript

**Node:** 8.1.0

I have the following prototype:

```
String.prototype.toSlug = function () {
  return (<string>this)
    .trim()
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')
    .replace(/^-+/, '')
    .replace(/-+$/, '')
}
```

When I use it, like this:

```
// Mongoose Database Model:
let project = new ProjectModel
project.slug = title.toSlug()
```

It doesn't seem to work correctly. All it did was remove the first space and add a dash as seen here:

```
// Original: "Bed Time Stories"
// Outputs: "BedTime-Stories"
// Expected: "bed-time-stories"
```

As you can see it didn't even convert the strings to lowercase.

However when I test this at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hb8L6a8/), it creates the correct output string. What is causing this?

Comment: Is that literally how you've typed it, with `return (<string>this)...` ?

Comment: yes (copy and paste) without modifications

Comment: That's Typescript, are you using that in Node as well as the Fiddle

Comment: Yes: https://jsfiddle.net/2hb8L6a8/

Comment: That is a strange output, I can't really see why Typescript wouldn't be able to compile something that simple, but it seems neither `toLowerCase` or the global replacements work ?

Comment: sidenote: you can simplify this code to `return (<string>this).toLowerCase().replace(/[\s-]+/g, '-').replace(/^-+|-+$|[^\w\-]+/g, '')`

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, it had to do with `pm2` not reloading the changes that I made for some reason...

Comment: Please do not mutate built-in objects and/or their prototypes.

Comment: @mscdex May I ask why?

Answer (score 1):

```
interface String {
    toSlug(): string;
}

String.prototype.toSlug = function () {
  return (<string>this)
    .trim()
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')
    .replace(/^-+/, '')
    .replace(/-+$/, '')
}

var str = "Bed Time Stories";

console.log(str.toSlug());
```

I found the error, The interface provides the contract for TypeScript, allowing visibility of the new method. The JavaScript implementation provides the code that will be executed when the method is called. That was missing from the code

Sources : [Extending functionality in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897659/extending-functionality-in-typescript)

Comment: I am using node `8.1.0` If that makes a difference

Comment: Removing the typescript element doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I believe I found the error, please see updated answer

Comment: I had that in my code, I just didn't post it. But the answer was that my `pm2` was not loading changes even though it was watching for changes. Killing the `pm2` process and starting a new one fixes the issue.