# How to extend the built-in Array Type on Typescript with the extend method? Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'String'

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, extend, extends

For reference, I am using React `16.9.0` and Typescript `3.5.3`.

On this question [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating), I found how to create the new method `extend` on the Array type:

```js
Array.prototype.extend = function (other_array) {
    /* You should include a test to check whether other_array really is an array */
    other_array.forEach(function(v) {this.push(v)}, this);
}
```

But when I try to add Typescript support (for type checking the array type), I cannot find how to make it work. This is how I tried:

```js
interface ExtendedArray< Type > extends Array< Type > {
  extend: () => void;
}

if( !( 'extend' in Array.prototype ) ) {
  Array.prototype.extend = function (other_array: ExtendedArray< any >) {
      other_array.forEach( function(element) { this.push( element ) }, this );
  }
}
```

Typescript just keep insisting my ExtendedArray type does not have the `prototype.extend` attribute:

```
Property 'extend' does not exist on type 'any[]'.  TS2339

    52 | if( !( 'extend' in Array.prototype ) ) {
  > 53 |   Array.prototype.extend = function (other_array: ExtendedArray< any >) {
       |                   ^
    54 |       other_array.forEach( function(element) { this.push( element ) }, this );
    55 |   }
    56 | }
```

After searching more, I fond this other question [Extending functionality in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897659/extending-functionality-in-typescript), with this example:

```js
interface String {
    foo(): number;
}

String.prototype.foo= function() {
    return 0;
}
```

But if I try to run it, Typescript just strikes its rage:

```
Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'String'.  TS2339

    41 | }
    42 | 
  > 43 | String.prototype.foo= function() {
       |                  ^
    44 |     return 0;
    45 | }
    46 |
```

How can I extend a Javascript builtin the prototype with a new function on Typescript?

Comment: Your `.extend()` function in the first sample of code is wrong; the value of `this` in the callback won't be what it needs to be.

Comment: Although it could be a contrived example to illustrate the prototype extension, I'm not sure I understand the point of `extend` when `push` already does that. Can we not do: `arr.push(...arrToAdd)`?

Comment: **@ggorlen, Can we not do: arr.push(...arrToAdd)?** It will not work for large arrays as 1.000.0000 elements. This is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17368101/4934640

Comment: Ah, OK--good to know, thanks. If you're really pushing hundreds of thousands of entries at once then I'd be worried the performance of the `forEach` version. `for ... of` might be faster.

Comment: You need to define the interface in a .d.ts file and reference that, take a look at declaration merging https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html