# Extending the properties of existing objects like Date in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I need to declare a static **MinValue** property in Date. My javascript code looks like,

```
Date.MinValue = new Date("someDate");
```

I have found similar questions with answers But, it's all about just adding a function not properties. And also those functions are not defined as static. So, that's not helpful for me.

referred links,

1. [Extending Array in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802383/extending-array-in-typescript)
2. [How does prototype extend on typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766117/how-does-prototype-extend-on-typescript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can extend Date to have an additional static property. You can extend its prototype as follows:

```
interface Date {
    min: Date;
}

Date.prototype.min = new Date();

var x = new Date();
alert(x.min.toString());
```

To do what you really want to do, you would actually have to make a change to lib.d.ts:

```
declare var Date: {
    new (): Date;
    new (value: number): Date;
    new (value: string): Date;
    new (year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): Date;
    (): string;
    prototype: Date;
    parse(s: string): number;
    UTC(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): number;
    now(): number;
    min: Date;
}
```

And perform the extension in pure JS, to be loaded in addition to your TypeScript generated JavaScript.

```
    Date.min = new Date();
```

Comment: Is there any other way to define static property? without changing lib.d.ts.

Comment: I'll pop an answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955157/how-to-define-static-property-in-typescript-interface