# How to define static property in TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript

I just want to declare a **static property in typescript** interface? I have not found anywhere regarding this.

```
interface myInterface {
  static Name:string;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to model, exactly?

Comment: Consider using ‘class Foo implements Bar’ where Bar is also a class. You can ‘implement’ classes by other classes in TS.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can't define a static property on an interface in TypeScript.

Say you wanted to change the `Date` object, rather than trying to add to the definitions of `Date`, you could wrap it, or simply create your rich date class to do the stuff that `Date` doesn't do.

```
class RichDate {
    public static MinValue = new Date();
}
```

Because Date is an interface in TypeScript, you can't extend it with a class using the `extends` keyword, which is a bit of a shame as this would be a good solution if date was a class.

If you want to extend the Date object to provide a `MinValue` property on the prototype, you can:

```
interface Date {
    MinValue: Date;
}

Date.prototype.MinValue = new Date(0);
```

Called using:

```
var x = new Date();
console.log(x.MinValue);
```

And if you want to make it available without an instance, you also can... but it is a bit fussy.

```
interface DateStatic extends Date {
    MinValue: Date;
}

Date['MinValue'] = new Date(0);
```

Called using:

```
var x: DateStatic = <any>Date; // We aren't using an instance
console.log(x.MinValue);
```

Comment: @Rajagopal To be clear, you can actually extend interfaces in TS using the `extends` keyword. You just can't extend an interface with a class (which you would need to do in order to add a static property).

Comment: Steve - 'Because Date is an interface in TypeScript, you can't extend it using the extends keyword' - that's not right, is it?

Comment: You can extend the interface, but you can't extend it with a class, only implement it. I didn't make that clear.

Comment: I would second @Nikos opinion. Doesn't inheritance of interfaces defeat the purpose of enhancing readability hence decreasing maintainability? Is there anyone who could give a rational as to why use inheritance of interfaces instead of a new one?

Comment: @TomasHesse there isn't a single correct answer to that (first) question. These decisions are trade-offs between competing demands and the correct answer is to assess the trade-off in the appropriate context.

Answer (score 199):

Follow @Duncan's @Bartvds's answer, here to provide a workable way after years passed.

At this point after Typescript 1.5 released (@Jun 15 '15), your helpful interface

```
interface MyType {
    instanceMethod();
}

interface MyTypeStatic {
    new():MyType;
    staticMethod();
}
```

can be implemented this way with the help of decorator.

```
/* class decorator */
function staticImplements<T>() {
    return <U extends T>(constructor: U) => {constructor};
}

@staticImplements<MyTypeStatic>()   /* this statement implements both normal interface & static interface */
class MyTypeClass { /* implements MyType { */ /* so this become optional not required */
    public static staticMethod() {}
    instanceMethod() {}
}
```

Refer to my comment at github [issue 13462](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13462#issuecomment-295685298).

visual result:
Compile error with a hint of static method missing.
[image]

After static method implemented, hint for method missing.
[image]

Compilation passed after both static interface and normal interface fulfilled.
[image]

Comment: @Val Please help, how I can resolve this issue: `'constructor' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)`

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn you can post a question with detail and share me the link

Comment: @Val I'm following your tip and got IDE warning at: `return (constructor: T) => {}`

Comment: @Val I solved it: `return (constructor: T) => {constructor};`

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Thank you! modified my answer for this typescript warning.

Comment: If you want forbid to add other properties it's OK, but if you want that your class implements many interfaces you can have this error :

Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'IConfigurationFactory<IConfiguration>' but required in type 'typeof ConfigurationFactory'.

Solution is to transform :

return (constructor: T) => {constructor};

to

return <R extends T>(constructor: R) => constructor;

Comment: @Chklang Thank you! I updated my answer with your suggestion

Comment: Cannot find name `staticImplements`

Comment: How can we do this with an Abstract class?

Comment: If you use typescript-eslint, you'll get a violation for the no-op usage of constructor in the decorator. I think a cleaner way to fix the unused param issue is to instead name the parameter `_constructor` - then you won't need the no-op call to make the compiler happy. (Though you might still trigger the `no-unused-vars` eslint rule and that you just have to disable.)

Comment: I get an eslint warning 'Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types' that can be avoided by changing the definition to 'staticImplements = <T>() => <U extends T>(constructor: U): U => constructor'

Comment: I still get "argument of type XXX not assignable to parameter of type YYY". I have double checked, I have followed everything.

Comment: This is a good solution but still TS is behind with static method overloading so subclassing and trying to use this fails AFAIK

Comment: Hmm, I get "Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.   The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1"

Answer (score 40):

Static modifiers cannot appear on a type member ([TypeScript error TS1070](https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS1070)). That's why I recommend to use an abstract **class** and inheritance to solve the mission:

**Example**

```
// Interface definition
abstract class MyInterface {
  static MyName: string;
  abstract getText(): string;
}

// Interface implementation
class MyClass extends MyInterface {
  static MyName = 'TestName';
  getText(): string {
    return `This is my name static name "${MyClass.MyName}".`;
  }
}

// Test run
const test: MyInterface = new MyClass();
console.log(test.getText());
```

Comment: Can't define abstract static methods :(

Comment: You can't define abstract static methods but you can define abstract static properties. Here is also a great overview of how to solve the different errors: https://typescript.tv/error-ts/

Comment: @BennyCode No you can't.

Comment: this approach does not guarantee that the concrete class remembers to override/define the static prop, resulting in possible "This is my name static name "undefined"" output.
And as noted, one can't use abstract static either.

Answer (score 24):

**You can define interface normally:**

```
interface MyInterface {
    Name:string;
}
```

but you can't just do

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    static Name:string; // typescript won't care about this field
    Name:string;         // and demand this one instead
}
```

**To express that a class should follow this interface for its static properties you need a bit of trickery:**

```
var MyClass: MyInterface;
MyClass = class {
    static Name:string; // if the class doesn't have that field it won't compile
}
```

You can even keep the name of the class, TypeScript (2.0) won't mind:

```
var MyClass: MyInterface;
MyClass = class MyClass {
    static Name:string; // if the class doesn't have that field it won't compile
}
```

If you want to inherit from many interfaces statically you'll have to merge them first into a new one:

```
interface NameInterface {
    Name:string;
}
interface AddressInterface {
    Address:string;
}
interface NameAndAddressInterface extends NameInterface, AddressInterface { }
var MyClass: NameAndAddressInterface;
MyClass = class MyClass {
    static Name:string; // if the class doesn't have that static field code won't compile
    static Address:string; // if the class doesn't have that static field code won't compile
}
```

Or if you don't want to name merged interface you can do:

```
interface NameInterface {
    Name:string;
}
interface AddressInterface {
    Address:string;
}
var MyClass: NameInterface & AddressInterface;
MyClass = class MyClass {
    static Name:string; // if the class doesn't have that static field code won't compile
    static Address:string; // if the class doesn't have that static field code won't compile
}
```

Working [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20interface%20NameInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Name%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20AddressInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Address%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20NameAndAddressInterface%20extends%20NameInterface%2C%20AddressInterface%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20MyClass%3A%20NameAndAddressInterface%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20MyClass%20%3D%20class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20Name%3Astring%3B%20%2F%2F%20if%20the%20class%20doesn%27t%20have%20that%20static%20field%20code%20won%27t%20compile%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20Address%3Astring%3B%20%2F%2F%20if%20the%20class%20doesn%27t%20have%20that%20static%20field%20code%20won%27t%20compile%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: I get error TS2322: Anonymous class is not assignable to type

Comment: @FireCoding Which TypeScript version are you using? My examples worked with 2.0

Comment: This is a more straightforward solution than the custom decorator `@staticImplements`.

Comment: I think this is a great solution. for async static methods you can also use `reply(msg: IBotMsg): Promise<IBotReply>`

Comment: is there a way to define both static and instance methods or are all methods now static only?

Comment: How do I do this with exported abstract class? `export const Element: Serializable = abstract class Element {` doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @Ella Sharakanski I think you can do all the definitions, and then `export Element;` separately on the next line.

Comment: @dcsan I think you can use `MyClass = class MyClass implements MyNonStaticInterface {` in my code to make the class adhere with both static and non-static fields to respective interfaces.

Comment: @EllaSharakanski If you want `abstract` then best do it in 3 separate steps. First declare abstract class as you normally would. Then assign it to constant of type `Serializable` and then export class or the constant whatever gives you best results at the place of import. This will cause your code to not compile if you forget to implement properties from `Serializable` statically in `Element`. If you have further question please create separate question here on SO, because it's getting complicated.

Comment: Sorry, it was part of my original question, I only have this one question. I don't think your suggestion works, it says "Duplicate Identifier".

Comment: @EllaSharakanski Just use two different identifiers for const and class.

Comment: @KamilSzot Cool, I get it now, thanks. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTkA5OAWwgC4BnMKUAcyIF8ii4AjRqRGGQIANnHr006AMJiJhEmUZwwwBBWp1k-Vhy4QAHgAcA9lCEITIRlNn1aU7JFiIUAXltz6RIA

Answer (score 18):

### Solution

Returns an instance type of `I`, makes sure `I` is a valid concrete constructor and `C` extends `I`:

```js
type StaticImplements<I extends new (...args: any[]) => any, C extends I> = InstanceType<I>;
```

Or a most general version, that should work for more cases. Returns `any` and makes sure `C` extends `I`:

```js
type StaticImplements<I, C extends I> = any;
```

Interface with instance method:

```js
interface MyInstance {
    instanceMethod();
}
```

Interface with static method:

```js
interface MyClassStatic {
    new (...args: any[]): MyInstance;
    staticMethod();
}
```

Class requiring static method and extending with its own method:

```js
class MyClass implements StaticImplements<MyClassStatic, typeof MyClass> {
    static staticMethod();
    static ownStaticMethod();
    instanceMethod();
    ownInstanceMethod();
}
```

#### Notes

- Type check actually happens in `C extends I`
- Constraint for parameter type `I` can be changed as needed
- Return type is what class ends up implementing via `implements`; For `InstanceType<I>` class would actually implement an instance type, although `object`, `{}` or `any` should work

### Reasoning

Defining static methods in interfaces is being discussed in [#33892](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892), and abstract static methods are being discussed in [#34516](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34516).

Based on Val's and Aleksey's answers (thank you), this solution:

- Does not require additional runtime values
- Class own member information is preserved
- Allows constructor constraints

### Test

As is - [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCWBjAkgWzAGwhiAdsAM4A8aUEAHsIQCbFQEQDuUAFAHTfwBOA5sQBcUeARABtALoBKKAF4AfKPEAaKAGFKNeozTL5UNAWIICKCABVwEcooDcAWABQLpEQi8AZvAtQAsiDGpmJ+AN4uAJDuIeYQ-hDAABYA9nTsMiIEAK4YAEaeTs4Avi5uHt6+0IEa2PDExHCIqFARzpHMbFw8AsIqkrIigcFmFkWRIcgoCclpGVm5BbxFpa7OKHUNASC19YxIWLj4RIxNU5g4eIQkpDWbjQhT6qCQKV7buw3KbROPLZOoGapdJyMJQXiJbK8AhQAAMxXGAJQUBSLAIZ0BiWBGVa4Mh0KgAEYEVEYqN4li5qC8cAoTCAEwk9qoggjUIU2Yg3EQ2kEgDMTNWLhQKRMKVwnGwKX47Due04SKBVJk9igAHo1VAAPIAaWFouI4ogkulsp2904LIx00pIJV6s1uv1YolUplnQ+9wynDJ7KVdtVGu1evWBqNJvdrE9e29LLZcX9GXtQd1QA):

```js
MyClass.staticMethod(); // OK
MyClass.ownStaticMethod(); // OK
new MyClass().instanceMethod(); // OK
new MyClass().ownInstanceMethod(); // OK
```

If to remove `staticMethod` from `MyClass` - [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCWBjAkgWzAGwhiAdsAM4A8aUEAHsIQCbFQEQDuUAFAHTfwBOA5sQBcUeARABtALoBKKAF4AfKPEAaKAGFKNeozTL5UNAWIICKCABVwEcooDcAWABQLpEQi8AZvAtQAsiDGpmJ+AN4uAJDuIeYQ-hDAABYA9nTsMiIEAK4YAEaeTs4Avi5uHt6+0IEa2PDExHCIqFARzpHMbFw8AsIqkrIigcFmFkWRIcgoCclpGVm5BbxFpa7OKHUNASC19YxIWLj4RIxNU5g4eIQkpDWbjQhT6qCQKV7buw3KYVAA9L9QACivF4KV4UX+UEmLWh00SqXSch+vES2V4BCgAAZiuNYVAUiwCGdUDMERlWlAUcA0RiAIw4qIxUbxeFzJGU1HoqAAJgZ7QJBBGoRZs0RFKpNKgAGY+asXCgUiYUrhONgUvx2Hc9pxYaS2TIigqlSq1RqtQ1OALiXDRRkDfLFcRlRBVer2J0PvcMpwmcK9Yj7etHc7XRqPebiN6BUK4v67fYgA):

```js
class MyClass implements StaticImplements<MyClassStatic, typeof MyClass> {} // Type 'typeof MyClass' does not satisfy the constraint 'MyClassStatic'. Property 'staticMethod' is missing in type 'typeof MyClass' but required in type 'MyClassStatic'.
```

If to remove `instanceMethod` from `MyClass` - [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCWBjAkgWzAGwhiAdsAM4A8aUEAHsIQCbFQEQDuUAFAHTfwBOA5sQBcUeARABtALoBKKAF4AfKPEAaKAGFKNeozTL5UNAWIICKCABVwEcooDcAWABQLpEQi8AZvAtQAsiDGpmJ+AN4uAJDuIeYQ-hDAABYA9nTsMiIEAK4YAEaeTs4Avi5uHt6+0IEa2PDExHCIqFARzpHMbFw8AsIqkrIigcFmFkWRIcgoCclpGVm5BbxFpa7OKHUNASC19YxIWLj4RIxNU5g4eIQkpDWbjQhT6qCQKV7buw3KYVAA9L9QACivF4KV4UUmLUh00SqXSch+vES2V4BCgAAZiuNoVAUiwCGdUDM4RlWlAkcAUWiAIxYqL-KAxUbxWFzBHk5GoqAAJjp7TxBBGoRZs3hZIpVKgAGY+asXCgUiYUrhONgUvx2Hc9pxocS2TIigqlSq1RqtQ1OALCTDRRkDfLFcRlRBVer2J0PvcMpwmcK9fD7etHc7XRqPebiN6BUK4v67fYgA):

```js
class MyClass implements StaticImplements<MyClassStatic, typeof MyClass> {} // Class 'MyClass' incorrectly implements interface 'MyInstance'. Property 'instanceMethod' is missing in type 'MyClass' but required in type 'MyInstance'.
```

Comment: The return type of `StaticImplements` should be `InstanceType<C>` (this also fixes an error: "'C' is declared but its value is never read.")

Comment: @chocolateboy you are right, the type check happens in `C extends I`, so return type might as well be `object` or `{}`. It just feels more appropriate for class to actually implement the target instance type, rather than itself or empty object.
To my understanding, unless [noUnusedParameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUnusedParameters) is set, it should emit only a warning. In my case, it's ESLint that highlights it, disabling it for that line shows the TS warning only on hover, otherwise it's greyed out.

Comment: This can be simplified - no need to have a constructor signature in the static interface: `type StaticInheritance<TClass extends IStaticInterface & { new(...args) }, IStaticInterface> = InstanceType<TClass & IStaticInterface>;`
 See my answer for more details.

Comment: The OP is asking for static `properties`, not `methods`

Comment: The return type of `StaticImplements` can also be `any`. I know using `any` is frowned upon, but actually the static implement check is done when `typeof MyClass` is provided as the 2nd type argument. The return type does not contribute anything to the interface check at all. Using `any` makes this clearer and also turns off the type checker where it is not used probably reducing overhead. It is a great solution anyway, but I tweaked it to return `any`!

Comment: @anorzaken @bence-szalai
Thanks for looking into the type.

Interface constraint was added to verify interface was generated correctly.
In the answer, it verifies interface has a valid concrete constructor signature.
It was intended to be modified as necessary, which I thought of as an advantage of the solution.

Return type was defined as personal preference.

Written in the most general way, type `StaticImplements<I, C extends I> = any;` should work as well for more cases, so I added it with explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Static properties are usually placed on the (global) constructor for the object, whereas the "interface" keyword applies to instances of the object.

The previous answer given is of course correct if you are writing the class in TypeScript.  It may help others to know that if you are describing an object that is already implemented elsewhere, then the global constructor including static properties can be declared like this:

```
declare var myInterface : {
  new(): Interface;
  Name:string;
}
```

Comment: edit: posted as a full answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18837239/1026362)

Comment: At this point after Typescript 1.5 released (6.15.2015), here it is a workable way to describe static members of a class.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43674389/681830

Answer (score 7):

@duncan's solution above specifying `new()` for the static type works also with interfaces:

```
interface MyType {
    instanceMethod();
}

interface MyTypeStatic {
    new():MyType;
    staticMethod();
}
```

Comment: Which one of these would my class `implement`?

Comment: At this point you cannot use an interface to describe static members, only instance members. So in this example your class would implement `MyType` (as in `class Foo implements MyType`). The static interface is only real useful in definitions, when describing existing JS code.

Comment: At this point after Typescript 1.5 released (6.15.2015), here it is a workable way to describe static members of a class.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43674389/681830

Answer (score 7):

Another option not mentioned here is defining variable with a type representing static interface and assigning to it class expression:

```
interface MyType {
    instanceMethod(): void;
}

interface MyTypeStatic {
    new(): MyType;
    staticMethod(): void;
}

// ok
const MyTypeClass: MyTypeStatic = class MyTypeClass {
    public static staticMethod() { }
    instanceMethod() { }
}

// error: 'instanceMethod' is missing
const MyTypeClass1: MyTypeStatic = class MyTypeClass {
    public static staticMethod() { }
}

// error: 'staticMethod' is missing
const MyTypeClass2: MyTypeStatic = class MyTypeClass {
    instanceMethod() { }
}
```

The effect is same as in [answer with decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43674389/1113002), but without overhead of decorators

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAsAFDJnKgDOYcISqEYAFgPYAmAFAJQBcyAbi2BsA3CQC+JEqEixEKDNjwBlGmGAJkRUuRAQA7tz6LcEMTrLU46hA2bsjAoaIlTiAenfIWAaxIIWEGo0LFMAYQAbOEpKY1CVNQ1kAF5kBCiYkKUISOjKLRJyZBwAVwAjCKSrG2RqjTtWTi4tZEkLCiCaOggGh2b8VtdiEk9kaCgWKD4Aciou+kZG6Yp8gFtgGNAAc39A4JM8XJiARjjs1Wsk1PS8rPCM-O0i0oqqxM0620W+lra2ka840mM0+vTYyw2yHWmxAO2IAU6d0ODwATGdTBcatcHkicjinuQ5rQFvYmr8JEA)

Relevant [suggestion/discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892) on GitHub

Comment: This works! I liked the discussion on Github. `implements static X, static Y` is a good suggestion. `static` as a keyword before every interface should not be breaking anything though a bit ugly.

Comment: This forces you to type the entire class into an interface, or else it won't recognize fields you defined in the class
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAsAFDJnKgDOYcISqEYAFgPYAmAFAJQBcyAbi2BsA3CQC+JEqEixEKDNjwBlGmGAJkRUuRAQA7tz6LcEMTrLU46hA2bsjAoaIlTiAenfIWAaxIIWEGo0LFMAYQAbOEpKY1CVNQ1kAF5kBCiYkKUISOjKLRJyZBwAVwAjCKSrG2RqjTtWTi4tZEkLCiCaOggGh2b8VsLyTzRgGIg2ZDL0ZExlIbIQFjBspu0FweI2oA

Comment: @ShaMan123 well the question is all about the interface. Once you type the variable explicitly `const MyTypeClass: MyTypeStatic` - only member of interface/type will be "visible"

Answer (score 7):

I'm somewhat surprised at how overly complicated the top answers are! But maybe that's just because this thread is so old.

Edit: Actually my initial attempt proved to be practically useless after some testing, and this problem turned out to be somewhat harder to tackle than I had originally expected.

After about an hour or so of tinkering however, I think I may have just found the best/cleanest solution so far (building upon my initial idea)! If the question posed is *"How do I include static properties in an interface?"*, then I think this is a fairly decent answer. This is at least better than extending a class if all you need is an interface (compiletime typing/requirements/restraints). There's no real drawback (well, maybe one small one) to this either since the solution is 100% ambient (unlike `extends`-based class extension like some answers are suggesting) and classes are constants regardless (immutable references that are not hoisted when using the standard class declaration syntax instead of a class expression as I'm doing here). This incurs no runtime overhead and doesn't require runtime class inheritance. You can define the entire class (both static and non-static members) all in one (ambient class used as an) interface!

*Here is how it's done!*

```js
/** ./interface.ts */
// In a file module (best), or wrap in ts module or namespace block

// Putting this in a module provides encapsulation ensuring that no one is
// at risk of misusing this class (it must be used as a type only). 

// Export only a type reference which will make it error is someone tries 
// to use it as a value (such as in an `extends` clause, or trying to 
// instantiate it).

/** 
 * Other Ideas For Names To Differentiate From Actual Classes/Non-Ambient Values:
 * MyClassInterface or _Interface_MyClass or MyClass_Interface or Interface_MyClass  
 **/
declare class _MyClassInterface {
    static staticProp: string;
    static staticMethod(): number;
    readonly prop: boolean 
    /** 
     * Note: Above, readonly won't need to be specified in the real class 
     * but the prop *will* still be readonly anyway.
     *
     * Now for the only caveat!
     * It does appear however that you cannot mark anything private or 
     * protected in this pseudo-interface which is a bummer, only props
     * and methods that appear only in the real class can be.
     */
    prop2: boolean;
    method(): Function;
    constructor(p1: string, p2: number);
}

export type MyClassInterface = typeof _MyClassInterface;
```

now to consume the interface

```js
/** ./consumer.ts */
import { MyClassInterface } from "./interface" // type import

const MyClass: MyClassInterface = class {
    static staticProp: string;
    prop: boolean;
    prop2: boolean;
    protected onlyOnRealClass: boolean; /* this is ok since this prop doesn't exist on the interface */

    static staticMethod() {
        return 5;
    }

    method() {
        return () => {};
    }

    constructor(p1: string, p2: number) {}
};
```

note that the `typeof` keyword is absolutely essential here (if I recall correctly, it is because without it typescript thinks we are specifying the instance type when what we really want is the type of the class itself). For example when we do

```js
const a: MyClass = new MyClass()
```

*without* the `typeof` keyword, we're saying that `a` should be an *instance of* MyClass, not MyClass itself.

*`abstract` ensures you don't accidentally try to instantiate the class...*

Edit: Actually I'm removing the abstract keyword from my answer because it turns out that the real class actually inherits the property of being abstract from the ambient class (makes sense), and will therefore not instantiate w/o the compiler complaining if the ambient class that provides its type is marked abstract... just gonna have to deal with ts not erroring if the ambient class is ever accidentally instantiated. It might be a decent idea then to prefix the ambient class declaration/name with an underscore and/or include the word `Interface` in the name so its proper use is clear (edit: I have since tackled this issue by encapsulating the interface in a file module thereby rendering it private to all other code and then exporting only a type reference to it).

and that is all there is to it really!

Putting the interface into a module isn't totally necessary but it provides a couple small benefits including:

1. the "publicly" widely-used type-annotation that is used throughout implementation code becomes slightly smaller since it no longer includes the keyword `typeof`
2. unlike the wrapped ambient class/interface declaration, the exported/outward-facing identifier is strictly a type (alias), so an error will now occur if anyone tries to instantiate it or use it in an extends clause (or use it anywhere else a runtime value is expected)

I'm not supplying a class name for the Class Expression in this example because Class Expressions, like all Function Expressions, will just inherit the identifier that they are assigned to if a class name if not provided. So if your identifier is identical to the name you want for that class or function anyways, you can just leave it off. Or, you may provide one inline as usual and it will take precedence over the identifier. A class or function name can also be changed after function/class creation, but only via Object.defineProperty or Object.defineProperties.

FWIW classes can actually be `implemented` (at least in recent versions of TS) by another class, but the static properties will just be ignored anyways. It seems that `implementing` anything only applies to the `prototype` in both directions (to/from).

Answer (score 7):

[Winterhotlatte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69571314/533837) had a good answer that got me on the right track.

However it is highly inconvenient to force inclusion of a constructor in the static interface.

## Simplified version

Reversing the extends gives:

```
type Static<TClass extends IStaticInterface & { new(...args) }, IStaticInterface>
  = InstanceType<TClass>;
```

No need to add a constructor to the interface:

```
interface IMeow { readonly IsMeow: boolean; }
```

And used conveniently like so:

```
class Cat implements Static<typeof Cat, IMeow> {
  readonly static IsMeow = true;
}
```

Just like before it gives a very clear error if `static IsMeow` is missing from `Cat`.

Also like before it still works like normal in every other regard.

## Fancy readability (*subjective*)

Require an "implements" string after the type:

```
type Static<TClass extends IStaticInterface & { new(...args) },
  _txt extends "implements", IStaticInterface>
  = InstanceType<TClass>;
```

To demonstrate here is our cat again:

```
class Cat implements Static<typeof Cat, "implements", IMeow> {
  static readonly IsMeow = true;
}
```

## Combine multiple (*excessive*)

This really isn't needed, you can just repeat `Static<...>`, but here goes:

```
type Static<TClass extends InterfacesCombined & { new(...args) }, _txt extends "implements",
  IStaticInterface, IStatic2 = {}, IStatic3 = {}, IStatic4 = {}, IStatic5 = {},
  InterfacesCombined extends IStaticInterface & IStatic2 & IStatic3 & IStatic4 & IStatic5
    = IStaticInterface & IStatic2 & IStatic3 & IStatic4 & IStatic5>
  = InstanceType<TClass>;
```

To demonstrate lets upgrade our Cat with more complexity:

```
interface IPurr { purr(): string; }
interface ILick { Lick(human: any): void; }
```

And the usage looks like:

```
class Cat implements IPurr, Static<typeof Cat, "implements", IMeow, ILick> {
  static readonly IsMeow = true;
  static Lick(human: any) { /* obey me homan! */ }
  
  purr() { return "Prrrrr"; }
}
```

## A concrete static interface

If you use a static interface often, you don't want to type out all that `Static<...` stuff.

First lets just get this little helper out of the way:

```
type New<T> = { new(...args: any): T };
```

Now lets "bake" a static `ILick` interface:

```
type IStaticLick<TClass extends ILick & New<InstanceType<TClass>> = InstanceType<TClass>;
```

Voilá:

```
class Cat2 implements IStaticLick<typeof Cat2> {
  static Lick(human: any) { /* obey me homan! */ }
}
```

## What's *actually* happening?

We are simply requiring that `typeof T` implements something for it to be a valid parameter to our "static interface".

So if `interface IFoo { stuff }` + `class Foo implements IFoo` says `Foo is "stuff"` then what we are saying is `"stuff" must be in T for T to be allowed inside Static<T, ...>`.

So the `implements` part of `class Foo implements Static<...>` doesn't really say anything about Foo having anything special. Rather in a roundabout way, we are just saying that we have these fancy `<` brackets `>` and inside them is a VIP club that only accepts "stuff" rollers!

In other words we can write:

```
class FakeCat implements IStaticLick<typeof Cat2> { }
```

...see what I mean then?

We try to lessen this glaring problem a little by requiring `Static<TClass, ...>` to actually implement the instance type of `TClass`. But this does nothing at all if `InstanceType<TClass>` doesn't have any instance members - such as our `Cat2` class.

`FakeCat` *does* implement `Cat2` - because it's not very hard to implement: `{ }`.

## Demo

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCWBjAPAFQMIBt4Gd8oIAPYCAOwBMiBJC8gJwDN4UJ8sB7AWwCMkFCFSgAyKAG8oQgO4AKAHRL4jAOb4AlFAC+AGigB9YGWJlKNKACIkPMDgg9KwfJd0BYAFBQotOIlT0TKzs+r4IyCgATFAAvJJ6Pn4RAMyx8aFJqAAsaRIJYf4oAKy5ep7egRAsbBzc-ILCpuTUdJkoldXsYonhqNHiBSndg9nDbUXl3mkj7QxVwdADbf09halLvSg5G4VFAHyTcfT4CBTsGOAQmLgE+HsA3J6egkE1PgCyEFwyklCMEPAqFwKDgQD58J9vgAuKB8LhcezwCj3HTPOadaC0AAKAFdGIxfmA8Yw5BoYSdGIJVCjtGjXl1aAAZVAAa1+zJQLLkAAscTwkTCkSAyVAAG5cJBUGlPDwAellUAA8iyAITeOQYRhg4BcKAoXiOBhQLg44DGoTG5hQYDc6A4BpEHVQVQQM3wPW8MBIezEfFcRgqjSeFB4QhQLCIKA2OwOJx0XH4-RtNCgSBcK0R4D6ay2eyG5yuD5fGShDksvaSSYnQp-AFAkFg2gQ4tpYCMHEQR5eKDViJQMs8vkCqBCrRSWUAKmNfAgYMcUG5vCRaonCtpHkmRPxpN+-2AeIoVix+JPlmlHnXQA)

Comment: If the requirement for `InstanceType<TClass>` to have a _public_ constructor seems limiting, we can take full advantage of how the compiler resolves types to the best matching signature and ignore the accessibility modifier to accept private / protected constructors like so: `type InstanceTypeSpy<TClass> = InstanceType<{ new(): never } & TClass>;` ;-)

Comment: It works because technically `new(): never` _does_ fulfill the expectations of the regular `InstanceType<>` however the compiler (which evaluates and can see all signature match possibilities regardless of access modifier) will choose not to match against `new(): never` to avoid `never` if possible - giving us the real type (or falling back to `never` if there _actually_ does not exist any constructor on `T`).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Here is the solution

```
export interface Foo {

    test(): void;
}

export namespace Foo {

    export function statMethod(): void {
        console.log(2);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Exactly what I needed

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja I am glad to help!

Comment: so this is using a namespace `Foo` to stand in for a class definition? where Class Foo would implement the statMethod()

this seems a bit of a hack, esp since namespaces are kind of deprecated now...

Comment: @dcsan Yes, it is a bit of a hack. But what to do? A lot of issues of typescript are open for many years with label `waiting more feedback`. So you either wait until static methods are added to interface or do this way.

Comment: but also i don't quite get it.. the `export namespace` is actually your  Class implementation? That does seem to be bending things a lot. I wonder what else that breaks in Classes?

Comment: also does this method allow you to mix static and instance methods? or does it make every method now a static?

Comment: @dcsan This feature is called [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to define a static class (ie. all methods/properties are static), you can do something like this:

```
interface MyStaticClassInterface {
  foo():string;
}

var myStaticClass:MyStaticClassInterface = {
  foo() {
    return 'bar';
  }
};
```

In this case, the static "class" is really just a plain-ol'-js-object, which implements all the methods of `MyStaticClassInterface`

Answer (score 3):

You can [merge interface with namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes-functions-and-enums) using the same name:

```ts
interface myInterface { }

namespace myInterface {
  Name:string;
}
```

But this interface is only useful to know that its have property `Name`. You can not implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fairly simple way to do it:

```
interface MyClass {
    new (): MyClassInstance;
    staticMethod(): string;
}

interface MyClassInstance {
    instanceMethod(): string;
}

const Class: MyClass = class {
    static staticMethod() {
        return "This is a static method";
    }
    instanceMethod() {
        return "This is an instance method";
    }
}

Class.staticMethod();

// Has type MyClassInstance
const instance = new Class();
instance.instanceMethod();
```

Note that this doesn't allow you to make a class extend an interface like you could normally, but for many situations this is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this (without decorators) for my specific use case.

The important part that checks for static members is `IObjectClass` and using `cls: IObjectClass<T>` in the `createObject` method:

```
//------------------------
// Library
//------------------------
interface IObject {
  id: number;
}
interface IObjectClass<T> {
  new(): T;
  table_name: string;
}
function createObject<T extends IObject>(cls: IObjectClass<T>, data:Partial<T>):T {
  let obj:T = (<any>Object).assign({},
    data,
    {
      id: 1,
      table_name: cls.table_name,
    }
  )
  return obj;
}

//------------------------
// Implementation
//------------------------
export class User implements IObject {
  static table_name: string = 'user';
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

//------------------------
// Application
//------------------------
let user = createObject(User, {name: 'Jimmy'});
console.log(user.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions seem to stray from the blessed path and I found that my scenario was covered in the [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes) which I've paraphrased below:

```
interface AppPackageCheck<T> {
  new (packageExists: boolean): T
  checkIfPackageExists(): boolean;
}

class WebApp {
    public static checkIfPackageExists(): boolean {
        return false;
    }

    constructor(public packageExists: boolean) {}
}

class BackendApp {
    constructor(public packageExists: boolean) {}
}

function createApp<T>(type: AppPackageCheck<T>): T {
    const packageExists = type.checkIfPackageExists();
    return new type(packageExists)
}

let web = createApp(WebApp);

// compiler failure here, missing checkIfPackageExists
let backend = createApp(BackendApp);
```

Comment: Perfect for this use case. If you would rather have the interface be more "standalone" / general you don't need to have both the `new`-part and your `check...` method in the same interface. The `check` method could come from whatever interface and you just need to combine them at wherever before or on the `type: X` line. (FYI I'm not saying you don't know this, I'm just highlighting that for other use cases the `new` part doesn't have to be attached if all you need is the static method part.)

Answer (score 1):

Though static keyword not supported in interface in Typescript 
but we can achieve it by creating a **`function interface`** that has static member.

In my following code I have created a function interface **`Factory`** that has two static members **`serialNumber`** and **printSerial**.

```
// factory is a function interface
interface Factory<T> {
    (name: string, age: number): T;

    //staic property
    serialNumber: number;

    //static method
    printSrial: () => void;
}

class Dog {
    constructor(public name: string, public age: number) { }
}

const dogFactory: Factory<Dog> = (name, age) => {
    return new Dog(name, age);
}

// initialising static members

dogFactory.serialNumber = 1234;
dogFactory.printSrial = () => console.log(dogFactory.serialNumber);


//instance of Dog that DogFactory creates
const myDog = dogFactory("spike", 3);

//static property that returns 1234
console.log(dogFactory.serialNumber)

//static method that prints the serial 1234
dogFactory.printSrial();
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution has worked great for my use case of adding additional static constructors. I have tested it and it has passed all tests. If anyone finds a buggy edge case please let me know.

I made a generic type which takes in the interface and static interface.

It works for concrete and abstract classes.

I have designed it using conditional types such that all errors get propagated
to the class implementing the Interface rather than the interface itself.

**Note:** The error propagation allows for vscode quick fixes (implement all methods). The only drawback is you will have to apply the static keyword yourself because there is no quick fix available for that error.

### The Interface:

```
type Class<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type AbstractClass<T = any> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;

type Interface<C extends Class<InstanceType<C>> | AbstractClass<InstanceType<C>>, SI, I = {}> = 
    C extends Class<InstanceType<C>> 
    // ConcreteClass
    ? InstanceType<C> extends I 
        ? C extends (SI & Class<InstanceType<C>>)
            ? (InstanceType<C> & I)
            : (SI & Class<InstanceType<C>>) // Indicate StaticInterface Error
        : I // Indicate Interface Error
    // AbstractClass
    : InstanceType<C> extends I 
        ? C extends (SI & AbstractClass<InstanceType<C>>)
            ? (InstanceType<C> & I)
            : (SI & AbstractClass<InstanceType<C>>) // Indicate StaticInterface Error
        : I // Indicate Interface Error
```

### Usage:

```
interface MyInterface {
    instanceMethod(): number;
}

interface MyStaticInterface {
    staticMethod(): number;
}
 
class MyClass implements Interface<typeof MyClass, MyStaticInterface, MyInterface> {
    static staticMethod(): number {
        return 50;
    }

    instanceMethod(): number {
        return 100;
    }

    static otherStatic() {
        return "HELLO"
    }

    otherInstance() {
        return "GOODBYE"
    }
}

abstract class MyClass1 implements Interface<typeof MyClass1, MyStaticInterface, MyInterface> {
    static staticMethod(): number {
        return 50;
    }


    instanceMethod(): number {
        return 20;
    }

    static otherStatic() {
        return "HELLO"
    }

    otherInstance() {
        return "GOODBYE"
    }

    abstract abstractMethod() : number;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution like [Kamil Szot's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40006145/11899061), and it has an undesired effect. I have not enough reputation to post this as a comment, so I post it here in case someone is trying that solution and reads this.

The solution is:

```
interface MyInterface {
    Name: string;
}

const MyClass = class {
    static Name: string;
};
```

However, using a class expression doesn't allow me to use `MyClass` as a type. If I write something like:

```
const myInstance: MyClass;
```

`myInstance` turns out to be of type `any`, and my editor shows the following error:

```
'MyClass' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MyClass'?ts(2749)
```

I end up losing a more important typing than the one I wanted to achieve with the interface for the static part of the class.

[Val's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43674389/11899061) using a decorator avoids this pitfall.

Answer (score -1):

Simple example

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

abstract class Trackable {
  static TrackInstances: number;
}

class Pablo extends Trackable implements Person {
  constructor(public name: string, public age: number) { Pablo.TrackInstances+=1; }
}
const person = new Pablo();
console.log(Pablo.TrackInstances);
```

Comment: This prints "undefined" in the TS playground. Which version are you using?