# TypeScript Error On Implementing Interface

Tags: typescript, angular

Compiler Error-

Class 'MessageBus' incorrectly implements interface 'IMessageBus'.
  Property 'dispatch' is missing in type 'MessageBus'.

IMessageBus Interface-

```
export interface IMessageBus {
  dispatch: (eventName: string, info?: any) => void;
  listen: (eventName: string, callback: Function) => void;
}
```

MessageBus Class-

```
import {IMessageBus} from './IMessageBus';

export class MessageBus implements IMessageBus {
  static listeners: Object[] = [];
  public static dispatch(event: string, info?: any): void {
     this.listeners
        .forEach((l) => {
           if (l["event"] === event) {
               l["cb"](info);
           }
        });
  }

  public static listen(event:string, cb: (any) => any):void {
    this.listeners.push({event: event, cb: cb});
  }
}
```

Please advice on how to resolve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992514/typescript-0-9-5-how-to-define-an-interface-with-static-members-and-a-class-tha

Answer (score 3):

Thierry's answer is correct.

Your interface is not defined wrong. But a more idiomatic definition would look like:

```
export interface IMessageBus {
  dispatch(eventName: string, info?: any): void;
  listen(eventName: string, callback: Function): void;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should remove the `static` keyword for your methods in the class implementing the interface:

```
export class MessageBus implements IMessageBus {
  listeners: Object[] = [];
  public dispatch(event: string, info?: any): void {
    this.listeners
      .forEach((l) => {
        if (l["event"] === event) {
           l["cb"](info);
        }
      });
  }

  public listen(event:string, cb: (any) => any):void {
    this.listeners.push({event: event, cb: cb});
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thierry, Thanks for the reply. Although I am not looking to instantiate new instance of MessageBus. Hence the need for static. This should do the trick.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992514/typescript-0-9-5-how-to-define-an-interface-with-static-members-and-a-class-tha

Comment: Hey. I see the problem. Yes, this question is definitely what you're looking for. I didn't know the "assign the class to the interface" feature of TypeScript. But it's a cool one ;-)