# How to declare an interface with static method?

Tags: typescript

I want to declare an alternative constructor in interface - `baz` in `IFoo`, but seems like it's impossible in TypeScript:

```
interface IFoo {
    bar(): boolean;
    static baz(value): IFoo; 
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    constructor(private qux) {}
    bar(): boolean {
        return this.qux; 
    }
    static baz(value): IFoo {
        return new Foo(value);
    }
}
```

What is the way to do that and have a proper type checking for `baz`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define static property in TypeScript interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955157/how-to-define-static-property-in-typescript-interface) -- essentially the same thing

Answer (score 38):

you can do this with anonymous classes:

**In general**

```
export const MyClass: StaticInterface = class implements InstanceInterface {
}
```

**Your example:**

```
interface IFooStatic {
  baz(value): IFoo;
}

interface IFoo {
  bar(): boolean;
}

const Foo: IFooStatic = class implements IFoo {
  constructor(private qux) {}
  bar(): boolean {
    return this.qux; 
  }
  static baz(value): IFoo {
    return new Foo(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: nice solution !

Comment: @chris This still seems to be the way to go, researching after 1.5 years. I have generalized your solution: https://pastebin.com/v8Rf6g6Y Could you comment on that implementation? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. but doesn't seem to work if you need to inherit from Foo?

Comment: @shaunc If you want to inherit from Foo and expand its interface, you can make a new type which extends IFooStatic. It does work, though.

Comment: @ReedSpool could you provide an example?

Comment: @geoyws Sorry I don't have time at the moment. I can explain a little better though. Extend IFooStatic (which in my pastebin is called CMyClass) and IFoo (which I call MyClass). So you have IBarStatic and IBar. Then make a new anonymous class, like `const Bar : IBarStatic = class implements IBar extends Foo {}`

Comment: No worries I gotcha. I'm rushing for time as well. But I can imagine how it's done now. I've been implementing this in my code all day.

Comment: Does this work anymore? I'm getting:
```
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'IFooStatic' has no construct signatures.
```
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2mDKY5jALIDeAUMsgEZwBeAFAG5wA2ArhAFzXYsRwgAlNwzYA3GQC+ZMqEixEKUZlIVqcKPWE9MfAROlkEmEAGcwyLJhFW8BIsgC8yBCzinTyYAFsADn28IcE9lVUpjMzAoNgQwTE1fKGBmSGQARzYAD24qXn4QJ2R4FlMIQVJpShpNbVzdfLDKZCgIMDYoArAAC2BTADoMzLFkNUrkc3tiGgZmdi4dPSEbbEbKFraO5BAIAHdLbCZWDkFRqSA

Comment: @Danman you could add a `new(qux: boolean): IFoo;` signature to `IFooStatic` and get `true` from a `console.log(Foo.baz(true).bar())` as in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2mDKY5jALIDeAUMsiBAO4AUAjgK4AeAXMgEbYA2EcIAJQcM2ANwUucAF50AbnB5MIHbpj4DhaLJgkBfMmVCRYiFKMylJnOFDpa1GkPsMJMIAM5hkOkTrwERMgAvMgIPHAeHsjAALYADnyxEODRFlaUbp5gUEwIYJh28VDACpDIzOxcvPwgIcjwPB4QgqQGlDZ2DjUCGZTIUBBgTFB1YAAWwB4AdJViyJLtyF6BxDayCkoq1eq1Wunk-QNDI3XUND7Y8orKgotkBmRZHrvTPJgA5nQ60+t0ObdfrZ7IIxEA

Comment: I wasn't able to get `return new Foo(value);` to work in my case. However using `return new this(value);` was accepted.

Comment: This was the best solution in an easy to read way!!!!! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 4):

You can't define a static in an interface in TypeScript. If you want to have type checking for the factory method just remove `static` keyword.

You can still use the factory method like this over the `prototype` property:

`var FootInstance = Foo.prototype.baz('test');`

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces [do not support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#a5-interfaces) static methods.

You [can't use abstract classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2947#issue-71732167) for your problem too:

```
interface IFoo {
    bar(): boolean; 
}


abstract class FooBase {    
    abstract static baz(value): IFoo; // this is NOT allowed
}


class Foo extends FooBase {
    constructor(private qux) {
        super();
    }

    bar(): boolean {
        return this.qux; 
    }
    static baz(value): IFoo {
        return new Foo(value);
    }
}
```