# Typescript: instance of an abstract class

Tags: typescript

Ok. this is very simple, just to remove an annoying error message.

I have an abstract class Router:

```
export abstract class Router {
}
```

And an interface like this

```
interface IModule {
    name: string;
    forms: Array<IForm>,
    route: typeof Router
}
```

Now I have a class which looks  like this, and many others based on Router abstract

```
export class Module1 extends Router {
}
```

Now, I want to instantiate the route like this:

```
let module: IModule = { 
    name: "My Module",
    forms: [],
    route: Module1
}

let router = new module.route(); 
// TS2511: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.
```

The code run just fine, and the instance of router = new Module1() is made properly, but I obviously doesn't write it properly in Typescript because I see           `TS2511: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.` when transpiling.

What is the correct way to define this?

Thank you

Comment: are you sure Module1 implements all the abstract method defined in Router??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you have an abstract class, it's constructor is only invokable from a derived class, since the class is abstract and should not be instantiated. This carries over when you type something as `typeof AbstractClass`, the constructor will not be callable.

The solution would to be to not use `typeof Router` but rather a constructor signature that returns a `Router`

```
interface IModule {
    name: string;
    forms: Array<IForm>,
    route: new () => Router
}
```

Another solution if you need to access static methods of `Router` is to create an interface derived from `typeof Router` which will erase the abstractness of the constructor:

```
export abstract class Router {
    static m(): void { console.log("Router"); }
}
type RouterClass = typeof Router;
interface RouterDerived extends RouterClass { }

interface IModule {
    name: string;
    route: RouterDerived
}

export class Module1 extends Router {
    static m(): void { console.log("Module1"); }
}

let module: IModule = { 
    name: "My Module",
    route: Module1
}

module.route.m();
let router = new module.route();
```

Comment: Wait. I copied and pasted the code above ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAJQgFcZgo4BvAKDkbjQRgEtM4BbACgEoAXHABuENgBNacTBAB2KCLmAA6XBADmPAESkKVLXwDccAL50zMAJ5hgJcpSgBhfITgBeOFZsQAZnb1QhnRssg4+WLa6DgAiVGzCwJKglLLiRFFUzgRENKZ0waFU4Zi2AJIAshDiZEq0DEyyCFzAQmhQIepBTHBQ9i3+MXEJ4ub5oJCw0i5EldVKAIxwycCp6X3U9N0s7Jy8giJikrky8ooqappaszXA8wbGZmZ0SvBcVTdCFe+1Hrn1jI1mkIrpY4NclFoADT-Hp9ITg26jOhvOYqXp6ZR7IIvWEBdxwWTAADu3G+aL6-CAA)) and still get the same "Cannot create an instance of an abstract class." error.

Comment: Same issue as @semisecure

Comment: This solution is outdated, It doesn't work with TypeScript 4.4.3, but it works with TypeScript 3.9.9.

Comment: and what solution for 4.4> ?

Answer (score 8):

Note, second part of the accepted answer covers:

> if you need to access static methods of Router ...

The proposed solution doesn't actually work. Just spent fair bit of time trying to figure this out so though I'd add: the way to do this is:

```js
type RouterDerived = {new (): Router} & typeof Router;
```

Full example [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgSgewK4QFMoEBvAKAUoUmAgEtYEBbACgEoAuBAN2zoBNSSbADsw2ZAQB0ybAHMWAIhz4iitgG4EAXzK6yEAJ4AHAljyEoAESJ1uBQQF5SIggHcE7LisvaEAMgQjU2wAM3NVKA0yMjoRS1C4MwBJAFlsflxJUgoqEWAmAi5IKDi5aKoEKAsiiMsbUvt+PRiUNAx0zMkARgQCAA9CEX4MHyIcypp6RlZOHj5BEmExCWlZBUVOrIJu9S1dfUlEJkMtyS40jO2EZyXcynzCrk3DBDOCRQAae6qarnfui0yCd3lJqqopLNokdfpEbghXB4QVdJGCauwgA).

Comment: I guess it should be `new () => Router` (instead of `:`), shouldn't it?