# Not Another TS2511: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class

Tags: typescript

My problem is very close to this one: [Typescript: instance of an abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358162/typescript-instance-of-an-abstract-class) but it's also slightly different.  If it's truly a duplicate, I would like a reasonable explanation at least because I do not know how to solve this problem.

I've got a Base class:

```
export abstract class MyBaseClass {
   private thing: Thing;

   constructor(thing: Thing) {
      this.thing = thing;
   }
}

export type MyBaseClassType = typeof MyBaseClass;
export interface IMyBaseClass extends MyBaseClassType {};
```

The problem is that `MyBaseClass` is part of a library that I'm publishing.  Users of this library will build a class off of `MyBaseClass` and the library will then be a runnable solution.   They will be able to run their code by simply saying:

```
node our-provided-bin run -b /path/to/client-class-extending-base-class
```

In that script, we do a

```
const ImportedClassRef: IMyBaseClass = require(resolvedPath);
```

That `ImportedClassRef` gets passed through some methods and we finally say,

```
const dude = new ImportedClassRef(thing);
```

And I'm getting the dreaded: `TS2511: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces are just describing structures and not new named classes.

```
interface A {
  arg1: string;
}

interface B {
  arg1: string
}

// A and B are the same
let a: A = {arg1: ""};
let b: B = a;
```

That is why:

```
export type MyBaseClassType = typeof MyBaseClass;
export interface IMyBaseClass extends MyBaseClassType {};
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
type IMyBaseClass = typeof MyBaseClass;
```

and thus your problem is *exactly the same problem as in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358162/typescript-instance-of-an-abstract-class) you referenced*.

I don't know what kind of type `Thing` is supposed to be, but based on the assumption it's a fixed type, I would define it like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oCUIGMD2ATgCYA8AzsIcigDRRICuAtgEYSEB8A3AFC8BDVpUIDcwKLgA2A8uSgBZEACFZEAMIy5UAN68oBgkhGNxRABRQw1AG4Dg0YIlQAuWM5QBKXQF9ef3lBIKABJY2ABJGAEISkNLXJSGCgIAA8HJGJ5JVVyeNlyTgxdfQYIAHdzJxo3eBpPWv9+aQLsCAEpTVa0jKzFFTUu7R0fKAB6MahCCABHRgRp82nyfCkbCGIABXs4Tz5eI0ooBGYwIgdiIfIcADM3MMpI6Nj8uVIcwYSizBwOq+4oPwkBVjqdzhsrrdzCNvBMGPgUoRCERuEA):

```
type Thing = Record<string, any>;

abstract class MyBaseClass {
   constructor( private thing: Thing) {}
}

type InstantiableClass<T extends MyBaseClass> = {
  new(thing: Thing): T
}

class RealClass extends MyBaseClass {} // require(resolvedPath);

const importedClassRef: InstantiableClass<MyBaseClass> = RealClass;

new importedClassRef({}) // no error;
```

---

**Update: Why does this work?**

Abstract classes have a special constructor ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggRgZ2AJwIYGNgGED2A7JZAV0x2SgF4pVEUNgo8IB3ACgDpPVkBzBALmp4QAbQC6ASkoA+ISADcAKEXp8SWLTSYsAG1QIBGwvVwEUJYGUpQA3gF9qCOUsVNmRutr0HWUgPR+UACiyMhkglioeHg4DOjIEKjA0FFQAJZmUejQOABmQtSa9FDo3ghAA)):

```
type AbstractConstructor = abstract new(...args: any[]) => any;

const AbstractClass: AbstractConstructor = {} as any;

new AbstractClass() // Error: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class
```

which is not callable unless called from a derived class. To circumvent this, the type `InstantiableClass` defines a normal constructor that just returns an instance of `T extends MyBaseClass`.

```
type InstantiableClass<T extends MyBaseClass> = {
  /* no abstract */ new(thing: Thing): T
}
```

So the reason this works is that we just mimicked the structure of `typeof MyBaseClass` with the difference of defining a normal constructor instead of an abstract one.

Comment: Hey!  I got this to work!   Thank you!   You wouldn't by any chance know why it works?

Comment: Ah OK... so if we want to instantiate an instance of an abstract class, we need to create a normal constructor for it.  This makes a lot more sense.  Thank you again!

Comment: @MircoS. I don't get your solution. If you remove the `any` you get error at 
`const importedClassRef ...`. If you try to run it with the any, you also get error at the line where you say "no error".

Comment: @semisecure The line '{} as any' is just a placeholder for a real class that extends the base class. I've updated the example with a "RealClass" to make that more clear. Run should also work now on the first playground link behind "this". If it still fails for you, I need more specifics on the environment you running it in.

Answer (score 0):

In the class that takes `ImportedClassRef` as a parameter, I defined the props like so:

```
interface IProps {
   ...
   ImportedClassRef: MyBaseClass | any;
}

export SomeRunnerClass {
    private dude: MyBaseClass;

    constructor({..., ImportedClassRef}:IProps) {
        ...
        this.dude = new ImportedClassRef(thing);
    }
}
```

The `| any` took the error away but is not a "fix."   See `semisecure`'s comment.

Comment: Although this "worked" it was a band-aid to my problem.  Mirco S gets the answer.   Much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a fix. `MyBaseClass | any` === `any` and `any` means opting out of Typing altogether.

Comment: I added your comment.  I wanted to leave this here so that folks who tried this would realize that it's not a fix, either.  Appreciate the comment, @semisecure