# how to typecast T extends Class in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics

I want to avoid using any for clazz. Casting it to A doesn't allow me to create a new instance as it assumes it's an abstract class. What would be the correct type to cast clazz to?

```
abstract class A {}

class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
class D extends A {}

const clazz: any = getOneOfBCDRandom();
const c = new clazz();

getOneOfBCDRandom<T extends A>(): T {
  return [B, C, D][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
}
```

i removed the private state from the getOneOfBCDRandom function as it was a mistake.
The solution was to not use generics but:

```
new () => A
```

so this works as expected:

```
abstract class A {}

class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
class D extends A {}

const clazz: new () => A = getOneOfBCDRandom();
const c = new clazz();

getOneOfBCDRandom(): new () =>  A {
  return [B, C, D][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
}
```

Using generics was just my first approach

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358162/typescript-instance-of-an-abstract-class :-)

Comment: I think you just want `new () => A` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPjzKN). But your example code confuses me. Why do you have `getOneOfBCDRandom` as a generic function? Who chooses `T`? And why a `private` method instead of a function? And why return type `T`, an *instance* of a subtype of `A` instead of a *constructor*? And why "cast" `clazz` or even annotate it? If the question is "how do I denote the type of some concrete no-arg constructor of a subtype of `A`?", then the answer is `new () => A`. And if it is, or if it is not, you might want to edit to make the code a [mcve]. Good luck!