# Abstract static method on abstract class

Tags: typescript

I remember being able to provide an interface for a abstract class, something like this, but I can't find that code online anywhere. I am I unable to do it here:

```
interface AbstractParent { 
  staticMember: () => boolean
}

abstract class AbstractParent {  
  static example() { 
    return this.staticMember()
  }
}

class Utilize extends AbstractParent {  
  static staticMember() { 
    return true
  }
}

console.log(Utilize.example())
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=42&pc=31#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIICMDOYqLABTignGQG9kAoZZbOMYBAWQgFt1oAuZACgEpkAXgB8ydAHtxAGwhwQlAL6VKcLDjzIEUuJkxo1uBASIkw5GtVph6jZBAAecVgAcZ-c5ZrEwAVyghkMAALYEwAOjoGZjYOKH5LJSVKLR09AFUGKWAALxQHSBAAEz0MbENjYlIKKhpI2zro9mh3Ck9kbz8AnB8IBMVlBHEQTGkIMKlxAHMeDOAs3LCHJ1cIfj4gA)

Is it possible to have an abstract class require a static method?

Comment: ~Duplicate -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690133/version-of-abstract-methods-for-static-methods-in-typescript

Answer (score 2):

You can also try replacing `this.staticMember()` with `Utilize.staticMember()`: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=34&pln=7&pc=5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIICMDOYqLABTignGQG9kAoZZbOMYBAWQgFt1oAuZACgEpkAXgB8ydAHtxAGwhwQlAL6VKcLDjzIEUuJkxo1uBASIkw5GtVph6jZBAAecVgAcZ-c5ZrEwAVyghkAFUGKWAALwgAOjoGZjYOKH5LJSVKLR09YOBQiLt7SBAAEz0MbENjYlIKKhoY2zq49mh3Ck9kbz8AnB8IZMVlBHEQTGkoqXEAcx4snKiHJ1cIfj4gA)

Ideally, you want to use `static abstract staticMember`. But unfortunetly, it's not yet supported and doesn't seem like there's a good way to implement this.

Check our these discussions:

- [Suggestion: Add abstract static methods in classes and static methods in interfaces](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600)
- [`static abstract` methods and properties](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34516)
- [Allow specifying interface implements clauses for the static side of classes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892)

Answer (score 0):

This works without error, but does not ensure that `Utilize` implements a `staticMember` method.

```
abstract class AbstractParent {  
  static staticMember: () => boolean
  static example() { 
    return this.staticMember()
  }
}

class Utilize extends AbstractParent {  
  static staticMember() { 
    return true
  }
}

console.log(Utilize.example())
```