# Typescript class variables and error: "refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. . Did you mean typeof' ...". Why exactly?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This works in Javascript and Typescript:

```js
class A  { /* ... */ }
const B = class extends A { /* ... */ }
var x = new B();
console.log(x instanceof B, x.constructor.name); // true B
```

But if I try to declare the type of `x` as `B`:

```js
var x: B = new B();
```

I get Typescript Error:

> 'B' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof B'?

(Note, I also get the same error if I replace `const B = class extends A { /* ... */ }` with simply `const B = A`, which is what I had originally to make things as simple as possible, but updated on review).

I don't really understand why this should be the case. According to runtime Javascript `x` *is* a `B` (as shown in the console.log above). And *all classes are objects* ("values") under the hood anyway (the Typescript docs themselves equate classes to ["constuctor objects"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#static-members)). I'm guessing it's just a limitation of Typescript static analysis - it can't figure out that "B" is a constructor object just like "A" is and track down its typing?

And also, I don't think so, but wondering, is there actually a way to have this work in Typescript - know B is a constructor object like A and allow the use of B as a type??

---

P.S. I realize there are many questions on SO relating to *"Blah refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Blah'?"*, but I couldn't find Q&A approaching it as directly as above. Apologies if I missed it.

Comment: `console.log(x instanceof B, x.constructor.name === 'B'); // true true` actually returns "true false" if not compiled as typescript.  So "this works in both TypeScript and JavaScript" is a bit misleading. If it returns "true true" when compiled the compiler is doing something wrong.

Comment: This is `true false` in TypeScript also.  The question is just in error, and that line should probably be removed.

Comment: @traktor Your right, oops! The code is boiled down to bear minimum from a actual useful code. There is a slightly different case where we get true, true. I will update to remove or make clearer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write `class` declarations like

```
class A { a = 1 }
```

in TypeScript, you are bringing into scope *two different things* which are both named `A`.  One is the *value* named `A`, a class constructor that exists at runtime.  The other is the *type* named `A`, a TypeScript interface corresponding to instances of the class; such types don't exist at runtime.

Also note that a value *has* a type, but it is not itself a type.  And the type of the `A` value is not `A`, since the class constructor is not itself an instance of the class).  Instead, it has the type `typeof A` (expressed using [TypeScript's `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html)), which is similar to the type `new () => A` (expressed using a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures)).

The fact that the value and type are both named `A` is convenient but confusing.  It is convenient because it lets you use the one term `A` to refer to related but distinct things without requiring you to invent new terminology for each (e.g., `A` for the class constructor, but `InstanceA` for the instance type).  But it is confusing because it can give the false impression that these two things are really one thing, or that the relationship between these two things is somehow inherent in the name, when it's really just incidental.

---

On the other hand, when you write variable declarations like

```
const B = class extends A { b = 2 };
```

you are only bringing into scope a *value* named `B`.  There is no corresponding *type* named `B`.  If you want such a type, you will have to declare it yourself:

```
type B = InstanceType<typeof B>;
```

The lack of an automatic type named `B` isn't because the compiler can't figure out that `B` is a class constructor.  The compiler knows exactly what `B` is:

```
// const B: typeof B
```

And it knows that it constructs `B` instances:

```
type WhatBConstructs = InstanceType<typeof B>;
// type WhatBConstructs = B // this "B" is not an actual type name, btw
```

(Here I've used [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) to probe the type of the `B` constructor for its instance type.)

It's just that variable declarations name new values but not new types.

There is an existing suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#36348](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36348) which asks that when you bind a class constructor to a variable it should also make a named type corresponding to the instance type.  If this were to be implemented, then your `B` type would appear when you wrote `const B = class extends A {...}`.  If you want to see this happen, you could go there and give it a , but I wouldn't expect to see any changes there for the foreseeable future.

---

Anyway, for now, if you create both a value and a type named `B` manually:

```
const B = class extends A { b = 2 };
type B = InstanceType<typeof B>;
```

then things will start working for you the way you want:

```
var x: B = new B(); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9pmgXmgRmgXwFC+AHsA7CAF2gCE1pRIYBTADzIeIBMZ4kAjGgJhwBuXAHpRtEuSoAuaGQCeABwaEAZlXyKV0AOoALMGUoBhKWQBOAV2BkY6AJKkyYYsAYAVZQwA821RqUAHwi4vLeeobGZs7WtvZU0D4AtMny+gwWDADkMMSE0MxKhBAM7NDEYAC2DNBqhBbpAJYw-loR1I7Oru5eKn7e6lQh+ABuYI1MNMQMAO5UABQAlCJEpIQgDAB0IIQA5gtTTd1uAVQANNBMW2vkcWQNW5U1aKjo2ZTZK9Bhlla1fwYYwmVzknQqc0W3zChAA1mAFEA)

Comment: Thanks, reading. Not sure if effects but I made a typo in OP. I've replaced `const B = A` with `const B = class extends A { /* ... */ }` which gives the same error, and which is what the original code actually looked like. Apologies.

Comment: Awesome answer thank you! Defs giving my  on that issue :). `type B = A` is definitely progress. Though, it turns out that small update I mentioned does effect things :/. I can't say `type B = B` (circular reference error). Also cant do `type TypeOfB = B`  (B is a value error).

Comment: Yeah, that `B` type is just something IntelliSense shows; since it's a class expression the compiler shows `B` to be "helpful", which (imo) is even more confusing than just saying `(Anonymous class)` or something like `InstanceType<typeof B>`.  You want `type B = InstanceType<typeof B>` in general, which will produce a type that looks like `type B = B` in IntelliSense but actually works.  Anyway I updated my answer.