# Function variable assigned to a Class using Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Say you have a Typescript `class` like this:

```
 class CompExt extends Comp {
        public static sum(a: number, b: number): number {return a+b};
    };
```

The function sum will be sligtly different from the original class and it must be static.

Your actual code is

```
let ff: Function = CompExt;
console.log('the summ works fine',ff.sum(1,2));
```

Both the code editor and compilation will warn me this:

```
bas.ts(47,16): error TS2339: Property 'sum' does not exist on type 'Function'.
```

Is there a way to avoid compilation errors? If I use `any` rather than `Function` everthing is fine but I was wondering if Typescript supports such style.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't specify the type to be a `Function` because it's not a generic function, it's `CompExt`.

If you really want to specify the type, you can use: `let ff: typeof CompExt = CompExt`.

Comment: this is perfect. So I can have my editor autocompleting and correcting even if I use ff, which would not ocurr if I was using any or not typing. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution to your situation can be provided using decorators. Check this answer [Static property on a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955157/how-to-define-static-property-in-typescript-interface)