# How to make multiple classes contain the same static method name?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, coding-style

I created an IUserModel which has a couple methods that each subclass will implement.

I have two *User type* classes:
CoordinateLeaderModel and CommunityMemberModel

Each object contains a static method called "createFromJson(...)" which is unique for each Model.

I was wondering if there is a way to put the static method higher up in the hierarchy so that if I create another *User type* like "AdminModel" I will remember to create a static "createFromJson()" method.

Is there a specific design pattern to achieve something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define static property in TypeScript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955157/how-to-define-static-property-in-typescript-interface)

Comment: @estus I know it's not 100% clear but I think the question is more about abstract static methods, he wants to force the implementer to have a certain static method

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir If abstract class doesn't do anything that interface can't (concrete members, abstract members with visibility, etc), I'd consider it unnecessary abstraction. Any way, afaik, abstract static methods aren't possible, and interface is the way to go. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600

Comment: @estus I agree the design might be a bit fishy still not a duplicate of the other question

Comment: Wouldn't `createFromJson(...)` just be a single method in a separate interface called, e.g., `Unserializable`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [proposed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600) feature to allow this but it is not implemented yet. It is unsure if it will ever be implemented.

Without going into whether this is good design or not we could do a work-around that forces us to implement the method. We can define out base class in a module, but not export it, and export instead a function that takes as a parameter a function that will receive the hidden base class and return the derived class. We can then force the derived class to have certain methods:

```
abstract class _ModelBase {
    private isModel: true
}
export type ModelBase = typeof _ModelBase; // Export so people can use the base type for variables but not derive it
export function modelBase<T extends { new(... p: any[]): _ModelBase,  createFromJson(): _ModelBase } >(clsDeclarator: (baseClass: typeof _ModelBase)=> T) : T {
    return clsDeclarator(_ModelBase);
}


const AdminModel = modelBase(base => {
    class AdminModel extends base
    {
        private d:string;
        static createFromJson() { // will fail if this is missing
            return new AdminModel("");
        }
        constructor (n: string) {
            super();
        }
    }
    return  AdminModel;
});
```

The above implementation does not force `createFromJson` to return an instance of the current class, if we use typescript 2.8 we can also enforce this:

```
export function modelBase<T extends { new(... p: any[]): _ModelBase } >(clsDeclarator: (baseClass: typeof _ModelBase)=> T &  { createFromJson(): InstanceType<T> }) : T {
    return clsDeclarator(_ModelBase);
}
```