# supporting static and non-static methods in interface typescript

Tags: typescript

so apparently (i'm beginner) ts doesn't support static methods in the interface however there is a workaround explained it [Val's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43674389/3035659) answer. it works when your class has only static methods. but if my class is a combination of static and non-satic methods this will throw an error:

```
Class 'MyClass' incorrectly implements interface 'sampleInterface'.
  Property 'staticFunction' is missing in type 'MyClass' but required in type 'sampleInterface'
```

any idea how to support this?

```
export function staticDecorator<T>() {
    return (constructor: T) => {};
}

interface sampleInterface {
   staticFynction(/*something*/): promise<void>;
   nonStaticFynction(/*something*/): promise<void>;
}

@staticDecorator()
class MyClass implements sampleInterface  {
    public static staticFynction(/*something*/): promise<void>{
      //something
    }
    public nonStaticFynction(/*something*/): promise<void>{
      //something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally you need two interfaces; one for the instance side of the class, and one for the static side of the class.  For example:

```
interface SampleInterfaceInstancePart {
  nonStaticFunction(/*something*/): Promise<void>;
}
interface SampleInterfaceStaticPart {
  staticFunction(/*something*/): Promise<void>;
}
```

Then you can use your `staticDecorator` to ensure that the class implements the static side, and the regular old `implements` clause to ensure that it implements the instance side:

```
@staticDecorator<SampleInterfaceStaticPart>()
class MyClass implements SampleInterfaceInstancePart {
  public static async staticFunction(/*something*/): Promise<void> { }
  public async nonStaticFunction(/*something*/): Promise<void> { }
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Is it possible to ensure that the static interface is also implemented correctly by the class? So similiar to `implements SampleInterfaceInstancePart` but for the static part?