# Create typings for 3rd party library using class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've a third party library which has this ES6 class signature:

```
class Machine {
  constructor(options)
  static list(callback)
  create(options, callback)
}
```

I tried to create type declarations for this class but I get some errors:

```
export declare class IMachine {
  public constructor(opts: MachineOptions)
  public static list(callback: (err?: Error, machines?: IMachine[]) => void): void
}

declare interface MachineOptions {
  name: string
}
```

Usage:

```
const Machine: IMachine = require('lib')
Machine.list((err: Error, machines: IMachine[]) => { } //  error TS2576: Property 'list' is a static member of type 'IMachine'


const machine = new Machine({name: 'some name'}) // error TS2351: This expression is not constructable. Type 'IMachine' has no construct signatures.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955157/how-to-define-static-property-in-typescript-interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your declaration is fine. The problem is this line:

```js
const Machine: IMachine = require('lib')
```

`IMachine` actually refers to the type of an **instance** of the class, not the class (the constructor) itself.

Instead you'll want to use `typeof IMachine`:

```js
const Machine: typeof IMachine = require('lib')
```

Comment: Even if the 3rd party lib has `module.exports = Machine`?

Comment: Yes. that's actually true for classes in general in TypeScript. Whenever the class name is used as a **type**, it refers to an instance of the class. If you want the class itself, the constructor and the static context you need to use `typeof`.

Comment: With that I get `error TS2339: Property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof IMachine'.`

Comment: That seems to come from a part of the code you haven't posted. Maybe something like `Machine.create(...)` ?

Comment: My fault. I didn't specify it until now on the TypeScript class.