# Use import instead require with typeof

Tags: typescript

I have a require statement for a third party ES6 class like this:

```js
const Machine: typeof IMachine = require('lib')
```

`IMachine` is my type definition for the imported class:

```js
export declare class IMachine {
  public constructor(opts: MachineOptions)
  public static list(callback: (err?: Error, machines?: IMachine[]) => void): void
}

declare interface MachineOptions {
  name: string
}
```

How can I express this using an `import` statement instead?

**Update**

Based on [Aluans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66056940/90800) I created a repro: https://github.com/AlexZeitler/sourced-typings-repro

The compiler errors I get:

```sh
src/Market.ts:11:10 - error TS2339: Property 'rehydrate' does not exist on type 'Market'.

11     this.rehydrate(snapshot, events)
            ~~~~~~~~~

src/Market.ts:11:20 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'snapshot'. Did you mean 'snapshots'?

11     this.rehydrate(snapshot, events)
                      ~~~~~~~~

  src/Market.ts:6:15
    6   constructor(snapshots?, events?) {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~
    'snapshots' is declared here.

src/Market.ts:15:10 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Market'.

15     this.id = param.id
            ~~

src/Market.ts:16:10 - error TS2339: Property 'digest' does not exist on type 'Market'.

16     this.digest('init', param)
            ~~~~~~

src/Market.ts:17:10 - error TS2339: Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'Market'.

17     this.emit('initialized', param, this)
```

The `import` statement shows this warning:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'sourced'. '/Users/alex/src/sourced-typings-repro/node_modules/sourced/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/sourced` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'sourced';`ts(7016)
```

The sample in the original question is based on another question of mine which led to the question about typeof + require vs. import style:

[Create typings for 3rd party library using class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868450/create-typings-for-3rd-party-library-using-class)

Comment: `import { Imachine } from 'lib'`?

Comment: You cannot: ES import does not have a notion of types, and TS does not extend its syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the repo you provided, please do the following:

In **tsconfig.json**:

- remove `"compilerOptions.typesRoot"`
- update `"include"` to `["src/**/*.ts", "types/**/*.ts"]` (optionally move `types` folder to `src` and leave `"include"` intact)

Set the content of **types/sourced.d.ts** to:

```
declare module 'sourced' {
  import { EventEmitter } from 'events'
  class SourcedEntity extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(snapshots?, events?)
    public rehydrate(snapshot?, events?): void
    public id: string
    public digest(method: string, param: any): void
    public enqueue(method: string, param: any): void
  }
  // export default SourcedEntity <-- PREVIOUSLY INCORRECT
  export { SourcedEntity }
}
```

#### more context / update

When you hover over `from "sourced"` in your original repo you see an error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'sourced'. '/Users/ymagio/pr/so/sourced-typings-repro/node_modules/sourced/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/sourced` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'sourced';`ts(7016)
```

I am not sure why `compilerOptions.typesRoot` are not picked up properly and if `types/sourced.d.ts` is correct in the first place. Anyway: `declare module 'sourced'` is the advised - by TS compiler - way to provide typings for untyped modules and I used it successfully on multiple occasions.

I looked into `node_modules/sourced` and turned out my initial answer was bit of -- there is no `default export` and the module uses CommonJS `exports` of the shape:

```
{
  SourcedEntity: [Getter],
  Entity: [Getter],
  Value: [Getter],
  SourcedValue: [Function: _default]
}
```

---

Typescript deals with a lot of complexity and corner cases related to [different types of modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) (ES2015, CommonJS, AMD, UMD), so the topic could be quite confusing to be honest. My guideline is to stick to ES2015 standard as close as possible. If I am not sure what exactly is exported from a module I just try: `import Default, * as All from 'untyped-module'` and `console.log(Default, All)`.

Comment: Thanks, that what I did based on the answer from Aluan (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66056940/90800). One tradeoff I noticed is that in my tests, the type information doesn't exist (I could "include" my test folder so it will work). I would like to understand the differences (benefits / tradeoffs) of both answers.

Answer (score 0):

Scrap that approach.

Instead

**extra-types/lib.d.ts**

```
export = IMachine;

declare class IMachine {
  constructor(opts: MachineOptions);
  static list(callback: (err?: Error, machines?: IMachine[]) => void): void
};

interface MachineOptions {
  name: string;
```

}

**tsconfig.json**

```
 {
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots": [
         "./extra-types",
         "node_modules/@types"
      ],
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
```

Finally

```
import Machine from "lib";
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to wrap the content of `lib.d.ts` within `declare module 'lib' { ... }` and remove the `declare` keyword from `declare class IMachine` to make it work.

Comment: That means something about your setup is different

Comment: I created a repro: https://github.com/AlexZeitler/sourced-typings-repro based on lib I intend to use. The sample in the original question is based on another question of mine which led to the question about `typeof` + `require` vs. `import` style: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868450/create-typings-for-3rd-party-library-using-class

Comment: I've added more details about the errors/warnings to the question.