# How do I add a custom static method to an existing node class (e.g. Buffer) in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I found a solution to add a method to existing class in TypeScript. I have to declare an interface with the same name and method inside it:

```
declare interface Buffer {
    foo(): string;
}

Buffer.prototype.foo = function(): string {
    return "bar";
}
```

But what if I need to add a **static** method to it (`Buffer.foo`, not `Buffer.prototype.foo`)?

**static** keyword in `declare interface` section is not allowed and raises an error: `'static' modifier cannot appear on a type member. ts(1070)`

**UPD:**

For @Grey:

You still don't understand what am I looking for. I need a **VALID** (without `//@ts-ignore`) TypeScript implementation of **EXACTLY** this JavaScript code:

```
// my-module/index.js

Buffer.foo = function() {
    console.log("bar");
}
```

to let users do like this:

```
require("my-module");

Buffer.foo();
```

The problem is not that I can't find **an alternative**. The problem is I can do **exactly this** (↑) in JavaScript but can not in TypeScript. Shouldn't TypeScript be absolutely compatible with JavaScript on the module-structure level at least? I mean, is it normal that I can't implement in TS a module which I can easily implement in JS?

Comment: A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955157/how-to-define-static-property-in-typescript-interface) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955157/how-to-define-static-property-in-typescript-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955157/how-to-define-static-property-in-typescript-interface)

Comment: @Grey It's not actually what I'm looking for. If I understand correctly, they suggest to add an auxiliary interface and then use it to call this static method. But I want to let users of my module (which is nothing but extension of node's Buffer) call it directly with `Buffer.foo` (in JS or TS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. The idea is the same as you already did before.

Imagine we want to add a static method to `Array`

You need to:

- Find the declaration for the constructor
- Declare new interface for the constructor with desired method

PoC:

```js
declare interface ArrayConstructor {
    foo(): string;
}

Array.foo = () => `hello from static method`;

Array.foo()
```

For your case, it will look like

```
declare interface Uint8ArrayConstructor {
    foo: () => string;
}

Buffer.foo()
```

P.S. TSC 3.9.6

Comment: What do you mean saying "find the declaration for the constructor"? I've tried the same with `BufferConstructor` but VSCode still says me, that Buffer has no member called foo. Does it mean that Buffer's constructor is called in another way? How to find its actual name then?

Comment: Please check the update, I think this is what you need (unless we are talking about different buffers)

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. For `ArrayConstructor` and `Array.foo` doesn't work too. Watch the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/tn97fn
Version of TS is 3.9.6 too and VSCode is up-to-date too, of course.

Comment: Looks like magic. Let's do double-check. Create index.ts file. Put here code from the first example. Compile it with TSC (don't look into the VSCode errors). Will it compiles? I am doing the same.

Comment: Yes, it really works in the newly created empty `index.ts`. I found my mistake which caused the problem. Hard to explain but it was just my inattention. Sorry for trouble you and huge thanks!

Comment: No worries, you also give me a nice hint :)

Comment: The interesting thing is that this trick doesn't work if file contains any `import` statement. Any ideas about it?

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

**Following your response:** *But I want to let users of my module (which is nothing but extension of node's Buffer) call it directly with Buffer.foo*

```
class CustomBuffer extends Buffer {
    public static foo() {
        console.log('I am foo');
    }
}

CustomBuffer.foo(); // I am foo
const buff = CustomBuffer.from('hello world', 'utf8');
console.log(buff); // <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64>
```