# How to provide types to for static class members

Tags: typescript

I have a set of classes that all should have some common properties and type restraints.

Think of how `Uint8Array` and `Uint16Array` are similar.

The first thing that might come to mind for comparing them could be:

```
interface TypedArray {
    static of(...args: number[]): TypedArray;
    static from(args: IterableIterator<number>): TypedArray;
    [index: number]: number;
}

class Uint8Array implements TypedArray {
    ...
}

class Uint16Array implements TypedArray {
    ...
}
```

I thought that a generic interface would've described what I wanted, but static members aren't allowed in interfaces.

The question [How to define static property in TypeScript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955157/how-to-define-static-property-in-typescript-interface) is somewhat similar to this, but none of the provided solutions worked for what I'm doing, and I don't particularly care if the solution uses an interface.

Any situation that makes all of the classes more generic than they have to be, won't fit my use.

Consider the following situation, where I want the most specific types possible:

```
interface X {
    // static prop(): number;
    foo?(): void;
    bar?(): void;
}

class Y implements X {
    static prop() { return 2; }
    foo() {};
    // bar: undefined
}

new Y().foo(); // okay

class Z implements X {
    static prop() { return 4; }
     // foo: undefined
    bar() {};
}

new Z().foo(); // error
```

In contrast, if I were to do something like this:

```
interface I {
    prop?(): void;
}

const C: I = class {
    static prop() {}
}
```

I would now have lost information about the actual class, since, in reality, it *does* have the `prop` method.

But that doesn't address the static properties of the classes, how can I provide a type for both?

Furthermore, my classes extend from other classes, so abstract classes won't fit here.

Comment: Your problem is not clear: you get an error because you're trying to call an undefined function.

Comment: @zerkms Just edited the post/question, did it help?