# How to implement static class contracts in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, interface, static

We are developing a component library based on lit and TypeScript.

To be able to generate certain stuff (which doesn't want to instantiate the classes), we need to make sure all the component classes implement a static getter for a certain property (which is what I refer to as a contract).

Example:

```js
interface IComponent {
  readonly BAR: string
}

class Foo implements IComponent {
  static get BAR() { return 'foo'; }
}
```

See [TypeScript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2BbADpkCcZAbwChlLkoI4ATAgGwE9kAhAQQCUAuZAZzBRQAczIBfMmQSM4-fsgBimTMmB5GEbETAKMOfIWLkqAsHDDAEyERDDtuACgCUpCqao0wAVyghkAOQwKgEA3O6UkuJAA).

The example throws

```bash
Class 'Foo' incorrectly implements interface 'IComponent'.
  Property 'BAR' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'IComponent'.
```

The example fails because for hard-to-understand reasons despite this being a much-requested feature for almost 7 years, to this day [TypeScript interfaces do not support static members of a class](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892).

I am looking for a TS-compatible, reasonable way to ensure developers implement this `static get BAR() { return 'foo' }` when they develop components.

Comment: Why won't you use abstract properties / methods  ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Because we're extending a third-party class (`litElement`) which we have no control over, and we don't want to extend it. This would have been an excellent use case for an interface in my head, but unfortunately the TypeScript developers think different.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65846848/2887218), and as such, all I know of are workarounds like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5zaBm).  Does that address your question fully or am I missing something?  (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz I agree it's mostly a duplicate, but tbh I was hoping for an easier-to-grab solution to this deerly missing feature in TS. Making sure classes implement static props/methods without having to extend abstract classes (which also compromise on the actual code!) seems like such a basic OOP requirement I still cannot believe TS hasn't been supporting this from the very beginnings, let alone not to this day.

Comment: I understand your frustration. I'm closing this as a duplicate of the other because the situation has not changed since the other one was opened. I don't know what to say about TS implementing it other than to encourage you and anyone you know who cares about this to upvote the GitHub issue to increase its priority among the many other requested but as-yet-unimplemented features.