# Are there valid reasons why constructor can't be typed as a callable object with static members or is it just a typescript limitation?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Interfaces for static properties / methods are not officially supported by typescript [1](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34516) [2](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892) but it is possible to achieve them through some workarounds, e.g. the `@staticImplements` decorator in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43674389/1412255 .

I wanted to try a different workaround: where instead of using a decorator, I could perhaps put static fields on `constructor` field. e.g.

```
interface ICtor<T> {
  staticField : string;
  staticMethod() : void;
  () : T;
}

interface I<T> {
   someMethod() : void;
   constructor: ICtor<T>; 
}

class C implements I<C> {
   someMethod() {}
   constructor() {}
   static staticField = "";
   static staticMethod() : void {};
}
```

I expected this to typecheck, but instead I get an error: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAICSBhKB7OAHgBUA+dAb1HXQGcokowUAxMGAGwBN0AuOqHEgBzANzUBjZgFkYUABZ4uACgCUfdADc8YLuJA01G4voC+oUJFiJUGTCXJUDNWngC2MWQqVH+23fo06Ch4EPRwAK4o+HD8ODEOouig5iCgKBxItLTo2OhgbgAOHDAe0Dn22I4SdO6ecooq6hSpQSFhglExRi019FIokkys7NzoALzoAERTgS4Mw0MyDT7qfjo8LWZAA)

> Class 'C' incorrectly implements interface 'I'. Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible. Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'ICtor'. Type 'Function' is missing the following properties from type 'ICtor': staticField, staticMethod

Is something wrong with my reasoning and this *shouldn't ideally typecheck* or is my reasoning correct and this would appear to be a limitation in typescript compiler?

Comment: you should use `new():any` to type constructor

Comment: @captain-yossarian where do you put that? Isn't that the same as what `@staticImplements` decorator is doing?

Comment: Here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgZ2AQzgY2gbwFBSsgcwgC4o4BXAWwCMIAnAbmwF9tsBLOYegM2Q1gBhAPaJgdcmmDC6UHHjgQA7gApCJMlVp0AlKXhJUGFmzQAbZAgRQAqgnpR2lMGYiUIXawZTosuKGiiSBJSMipg5NRm7Gj4RKQUNPQ6cv54wAAW7AgAdOpQALxxEEx4rKymQcBQfKF0IIVQKuaW+iJiIdJ0ADTFCVrJhQB8ZMoBFghqRDpMQA

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how decorators work. I don't like them )

Comment: Thanks. But this has no way of enforcing that the class is implemented with the right static methods (the `IConstructor` interface), it only enforces that the call to `factory` has the right param. That's why I had wanted to go the other way: instead of `new` on class, use `constructor` on the object.

Comment: This is interesting.  I can see what you are trying to do, but the TS compiler is looking for the static methods specifically as properties of the `constructor()` function rather than seeing the whole class as the constructor.