# Typing is not checked for classes returned by factory function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typescript-generics

I've created a module factory function with returns a class annotated by `@Module({})`. My problem is, the class depends on function arguments `providerToken` and `strategy` so I cannot move it outside the function. When I run the code, it works perfectly fine but the value for `forRoot` and `forRootAsync` is not properly checked for types. Infact typescript doesn't throw any error about that. Also what should be my return value of the function. I've put it `any` to avoid errors for now.

**This is how I'm using the function to create a module**

```
const TwitterAuthModule =
  createHybridAuthModule<TwitterAuthModuleOptions>(
    TWITTER_HYBRID_AUTH_OPTIONS,
    TwitterAuthStrategy
  );
```

**Module creator factory**

```
export function createHybridAuthModule<T>(
  providerToken: string,
  strategy: any
): any {
  @Module({})
  class NestHybridAuthModule {
    static forRoot(options: T): DynamicModule {
      return {
        module: NestHybridAuthModule,
        providers: [
          {
            provide: providerToken,
            useValue: options,
          },
          strategy,
        ],
      };
    }

    static forRootAsync(
      options: ModuleAsyncOptions<ModuleOptionsFactory<T>, T>
    ): DynamicModule {
      return {
        module: NestHybridAuthModule,
        providers: [...this.createAsyncProviders(options), strategy],
      };
    }

    private static createAsyncProviders(
      options: ModuleAsyncOptions<ModuleOptionsFactory<T>, T>
    ): Provider[] {
      if (options.useExisting || options.useFactory) {
        return [this.createAsyncOptionsProvider(options)];
      }
      const useClass = options.useClass as Type<ModuleOptionsFactory<T>>;
      return [
        this.createAsyncOptionsProvider(options),
        {
          provide: useClass,
          useClass,
        },
      ];
    }

    private static createAsyncOptionsProvider(
      options: ModuleAsyncOptions<ModuleOptionsFactory<T>, T>
    ): Provider {
      if (options.useFactory) {
        return {
          provide: providerToken,
          useFactory: options.useFactory,
          inject: options.inject || [],
        };
      }

      const inject = [
        (options.useClass || options.useExisting) as Type<
          ModuleOptionsFactory<T>
        >,
      ];

      return {
        provide: providerToken,
        useFactory: async (optionsFactory: ModuleOptionsFactory<T>) =>
          await optionsFactory.createModuleOptions(),
        inject,
      };
    }
  }

  return NestHybridAuthModule;
}
```

**Usage of the created module. The value of forRoot is never checked for types**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TwitterAuthModule.forRoot({
      consumerKey: '********',
      consumerSecret: '******',
      callbackURL: '*******',
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason why typescript not check your types is that it treat `NestHybridAuthModule` as `any` because `createHybridAuthModule` function return type is `any`. Remove it and allow typescript infer return type.

In case there is `--noImplicitReturns` used you can use generic interface

**Edit:**
Thanks for pointing it.
corrected example:

```
interface INestHybridAuthModule<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): any,
    forRoot(options: T): DynamicModule
}
export function createHybridAuthModule<T>(
    providerToken: string,
    strategy: any
): INestHybridAuthModule<T> {
    class NestHybridAuthModule {
        static forRoot(options: T): DynamicModule {
            // logic here
        }
    }
    return NestHybridAuthModule
}
```

**original:**

simplified example:

```
interface INestHybridAuthModule<T> {
    forRoot(options: T): DynamicModule
}
export function createHybridAuthModule<T>(
    providerToken: string,
    strategy: any
): new (...args: any[]) => INestHybridAuthModule<T> {
    class NestHybridAuthModule {
        forRoot(options: T): DynamicModule {
            // logic here
        }
    }
    return NestHybridAuthModule
}
```

Comment: forRoot is static property which you removed. It throws that class doesn't implement forRoot.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43674389/1029506 and implemented it using a customer decorator:

```
export interface INestHybridAuthModule<T> {
  forRoot(options: T): DynamicModule;
}

function staticImplements<T>() {
  return <U extends T>(constructor: U) => {
    constructor;
  };
}

function createHybridAuthModule<T>(
    providerToken: string,
    strategy: any
  ): INestHybridAuthModule<T> {
    @Module({})
    @staticImplements<INestHybridAuthModule<T>>()
    class NestHybridAuthModule {
      static forRoot(options: T): DynamicModule {
        // code here
      }
  
      static forRootAsync(
        options: ModuleAsyncOptions<ModuleOptionsFactory<T>, T>
      ): DynamicModule {
        // Code here
      }
  
      private static createAsyncProviders(
        options: ModuleAsyncOptions<ModuleOptionsFactory<T>, T>
      ): Provider[] {
        // Code here
      }
  
      private static createAsyncOptionsProvider(
        options: ModuleAsyncOptions<ModuleOptionsFactory<T>, T>
      ): Provider {
        // Code here
      }
    }
  
    return NestHybridAuthModule;
  }
```

**And Finally**

```
const TwitterAuthModule: INestHybridAuthModule<TwitterAuthModuleOptions> = createHybridAuthModule<
  TwitterAuthModuleOptions
>(TWITTER_HYBRID_AUTH_OPTIONS, TwitterAuthStrategy);
```