# How to implements generic interface on abstract class with static functions

Tags: typescript, class, interface, typescript-generics

```
interface IEntityParams { 
  exclude?: string;
  include?: string;
}

interface IServiceResponse<T> {
  Data: T;
  ErrorText: string;
  Result: boolean; 
}

 
interface IEntityService<T = any> {
  getById(id: number, params: IEntityParams): IServiceResponse<T>;
  getMultipleByIds(ids: string, body: IEntityParams): IServiceResponse<T>; 
}


interface ICustomer {
  Title: string;
}  

abstract class CustomerService<T extends ICustomer> implements IEntityService<T> {
  
  static getById(id: number, params: IEntityParams): IServiceResponse<ICustomer> {

    //here api request will be sent to customers/id/{id}

    return {
      Data: {
        Title: "example",
      },
      ErrorText: "",
      Result: true,
    };
  }
}

interface IOpportuntiy {
  Id: string;
}  

abstract class OpportunityService<T extends IOpportuntiy> implements IEntityService<T> {
  
  static getById(id: number, params: IEntityParams): IServiceResponse<IOpportuntiy> {

       //here api request will be sent to opportunities/id/{id}

    return {
      Data: {
        Id: "example",
      },
      ErrorText: "",
      Result: true,
    };
  }
}


interface ISale {
  Total: string;
}  

abstract class SaleService<T extends ISale> implements IEntityService<T> {
  
  static getById(id: number, params: IEntityParams): IServiceResponse<ISale> {

    //here api request will be sent to sales/id/{id}

    return {
      Data: {
        Total: "example",
      },
      ErrorText: "",
      Result: true,
    };
  }
}


//i want to call like this
console.log(CustomerService.getById(1,{
  exclude:"example",
  include:"example"
}))

console.log(OpportunityService.getById(1,{
  exclude:"example",
  include:"example"
}))

console.log(SaleService.getById(1,{
  exclude:"example",
  include:"example"
}))
```

I want to use IEntityService interface in my class services.
But i got this error:

> Class 'CustomerService' incorrectly implements interface
> 'IEntityService'. Type 'CustomerService'  is missing the
> following properties from type 'IEntityService': getById,
> getMultipleByIds(2420)

typescript playground link: [here](https://tsplay.dev/WzO3Lw)

Comment: This answer shows a simple `staticImplements` decorator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43674389/62076 Does that answer your question?

Comment: Just know that when a class has a generic parameter, that is for the _instances_ of that class so that each instance may have a different generic parameter type. So static members must have their types declared explicitly. But otherwise, that decorator I mentioned above should work. See https://tsplay.dev/mxYABW

Answer (score 0):

that is because the static method does not exist on the *instance* in exists on the *type*. You call a static function like this: `MyClass.SomeStaticFunction()`. An instance method is called with `instanceOfMyClass.someFunction()`. They are not interchangeable.

The simplest solution is not to use a static method. Every static method can be implemented as an instance method. You may also use the static implementation and call it from an instance method that implements the interface.

```js
interface IFoo {
    getData(): {some: string};
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    static SGetData(): {some: string} {
        return {some: "stuff"};
    }
    static getData(): {some: string} {
        return Foo.SGetData();
    }
}
```