# How can I add a static member to HTMLElement class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

This is how I usually extend the HTMLElement prototype:

```js
export {}

declare global {
    interface HTMLElement {
        x: number
    }
}

let elem =  document.createElement('div')
elem.x = 12
console.log(elem.x) // -> 12
```

But as I understand it, this previous approach adds an "x" value to all instances of HTMLElement. I want to add a static method to the class itself, that would allow me to do something like this:

```js
HTMLElement.x = 12 // Property 'x' does not exist on type '{ new (): HTMLElement; prototype: HTMLElement; }'.

console.log(HTMLElement.x) // -> 12
```

I understand that the error message is asking me to declare X inside the HTMLElement type, but really I don't know how or if it is something I should be doing in general. The purpose of all this is to store a little dictionary of information relevant to the HTMLElement class but not in every instance of HTMLElement I create.

Thank you

### Edit

Adding the 'static' property won't work as shown in the following snippet:

```js
export {}

declare global {
    interface HTMLElement {
        static x: number. // 'static' modifier cannot appear on a type member.
    }
}

HTMLElement.x = 12
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define static property in TypeScript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955157/how-to-define-static-property-in-typescript-interface)

Comment: Not really, adding that throws the following error: `'static' modifier cannot appear on a type member.`

Comment: Perhaps you want `declare class HTMLElement { static x: number; }`?

Comment: That was perfectly fit as a solution, thank you very much!