# Unable to extend type in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation, typescript1.5

I'm trying to extend the jQuery unobtrusive validation interface with an additional method, but for some reason, it will not pick up the interface at all.
The snippet below is a bare snippet I tried running in the TypeScript playground as a test, but it claims it "Cannot find name 'Validator'", which is odd, considering the snippet follows the general syntax for augmenting a type in TypeScript, and the exact same syntax **does** work in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15481537/1139533).

```ts
interface Validator {
    parseDynamicContent: (selector: string) => void;
}

Validator.prototype.parseDynamicContent = function (selector: string): void {

}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is TypeScript broken... again?

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are not translated into JavaScript code. They only exist during compilation for type-checking. You cannot extend a constructor function that doesn't exist.The usual way to go about it would be to create a class that implements `Validator`.

Now, while TypeScript doesn't allow the merging of classes and interfaces, it *does* allow merging a var with an interface, and the var can contain an implementation of `Validator`. Here's how it works:

```
export interface Validator {
    parseDynamicContent: (selector: string) => void;
}
```

Then create an implementing class. You can keep that one hidden, unless you want other classes to extend its behavior.

```
class ValidatorImpl implements Validator {
    constructor() {}
    parseDynamicContent: (selector: string) => void;
}
```

Now you create the var to merge with the interface. The var will have a type that matches the static side of `ValidatorImpl`, which includes the constructor and all member explicitly declared `static` of coure. This variable will have the implementing class assigned to it:

```
var Validator: {
    new(): Validator;
} = ValidatorImpl;
```

Recall that under the hood a class is a constructor function, which is why the assignment is compatible. Put together into a single file, the code fragments above compile into this:

```
var ValidatorImpl = (function () {
    function ValidatorImpl() {
        this.parseDynamicContent = null;
    }
    return ValidatorImpl;
})();
var Validator = ValidatorImpl;
```

So you get your cake and get to eat it :D . You can implement `Validator` in classes derived from `ValidatorImpl` or from scratch, or forget about classes altogether -- any record you create on the fly that contains a member `parseDynamicContent` with the correct type will be accepted wherever `Validator`s are expected.

Hope that helps.